# Sum of Powers of 2

Tags: code-golf, binary

**The Challenge**

Given an integer input `x` where `1 <= x <= 255`, return the results of powers of two that when summed give `x`.

**Examples**

Given the input:

```
86
```

Your program should output:

```
64 16 4 2
```

Input:

```
240
```

Output:

```
128 64 32 16
```

Input:

```
1
```

Output:

```
1
```

Input:

```
64
```

Output:

```
64
```

The output may contain zeros if the certain power of two is not present in the sum.

For example, input `65` may output `0 64 0 0 0 0 0 1`.

**Scoring**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: Does the list have to be sorted highest to lowest?

Comment: May we output some redundant zeros?

Comment: @Adám going to say yes this time. I want the output to be somewhat similar to the binary representation of the number. ie 65 = 0 + 2^6 +0 +0 +0 +0 + 0 +2^0

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes only if the zeros are present in the list in the same way that certain powers of two may not be present in the sum. For example, `65` may output `0 64 0 0 0 0 0 1` since those powers of two are not present in the sum.

Comment: RE: "sorted highest to lowest" why add a restriction that was not part of the challenge and invalidates most existing answers? (Also what about little-endian?!) + it invalidates my Python answer since sets do not have any order.

Comment: @JonathanAllan it was always part of the problem based on the output I provided, but I added that restriction explicitly after your question as I realized some may have been confused.

Comment: As it was written it said "Given an integer input `x` where `1 <= x <= 255`, return the results of powers of two that when summed give `x`.". Note that it is a common misconception that test cases are to help define a challenge.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I've removed the restriction. I'll keep that in mind next time I post another question - I'm still fairly new to this. :)

Comment: I think you might want to state that any power of two may only be used once. Otherwise somebody could output "1 1 1" for the input 3.

Comment: Can the output be separated by newlines instead of spaces?

Comment: @SpookyGengar: you should probably say explicitly in the question that the output can be in any order.  I assumed from the test-case valid outputs that it had to be MSB to LSB, and only saw your comment while checking if an answer that isolated the lowest bit with `n&-n` was legal.

Comment: Is a leading zero in the output okay? i.e. `86` → `[0, 64, 16, 4, 2]`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?[...f(n&~-n),n&-n]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1i7PPlpPTy9NI0@tTjdPUydPTTcv1io69n9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahoWZpiYXqpCRiQGGmCGGiJmJpuZ/AA)

Comment: You're the only person in the whole world who can make me upvote JavaScript answers!

Comment: @sergiol, why wouldn't you normally upvote a JS solution? A good solution is a good solution regardless of the language used or who posted it.

Comment: @Shaggy Because Arnauld seems the only person to do such Javascript solutions. His answers are pure genius!

Comment: @sergiol Thanks for the compliment, but that's not quite true. I'm regularly outgolfed by more clever answers -- and that's what this site is all about. ^^

Comment: @Oliver I'm not sure. It seems like leading zeros (before 128) are forbidden. Otherwise, another possible variant is `f=n=>n&&f(n&~-n)+[,n&-n]`.

Comment: Nice alternative. Although there was no mention of leading zeros, the OP did allow zeros in the output.

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 since we may output zeros in place of unused powers of 2 :)

```
Ḷ2*&
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm1GWmr///@3MAMA)**

#### How?

```
Ḷ2*& - Link: integer, n         e.g. 10
Ḷ    - lowered range of n            [  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]
 2*  - two to the power of           [  1,  2,  4,  8, 16, 32, 64,128,256,512]
   & - bit-wise and                  [  0,  2,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
BUT’2*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98pNORRw0wjrf@H2x81rXH//9/CTEfByMRAR8FQR8HMBAA)

#### Explanation

BUT here is an explanation (note: I had assumed that we may only output the powers of 2 themselves and nothing else):

```
BUT’2* – Monadic link. Takes a number N as input. Example: 86
B      – Convert N to binary.                              [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
 U     – Reverse.                                          [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
  T    – Truthy indices.                                   [2, 3, 5, 7]
   ’   – Decrement.                                        [1, 2, 4, 6]
    2* – Raise 2 to that power.                            [2, 4, 16, 64]
```

**"Proof" that it works correctly.** The standard representation of an integer \$
X\$ in base 2 is a list \$\{x_1, x_2, x_3,\cdots, x_n\}\$, where \$x_i\in\{0,1\},\:\forall\:\: i\in\overline{1,n}\$, such that:
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot 2^{n-i}$$
The indices \$i\$ such that \$x_i=0\$ obviously have no contribution so we're only interested in finding those such that \$x_i=1\$. Since subtracting \$i\$ from \$n\$ is not convenient (the powers of two all have exponents of the form \$n-i\$, where \$i\$ is any index of a \$1\$), instead of finding the truthy indices in this list we reverse it and then find them "backwards" with `UT`. Now that we've found the correct indices all we have to do is raise \$2\$ to those powers.

Comment: "ASCII-only" Sneaky `’` there...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I guess `BUT2*H` would work though.

Comment: Pretty impressive that this works with an input of 302231454903657293676544.

Answer (score 13):

## Pure [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 20

```bash
echo $[2**{7..0}&$1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvBCkBAGAbvnuJLy0Gt0IZSXkQO2F9cdrW7N3n2n5Qyx5lmnvzGq3UI5MMyecJu0CpUqkCJWnXQNsLD4XYTVsSJhuwRQ3zDWz0FSPmTTMtmIYYqy84mz4srFeXI2hpivgE)

#### Explanation

```bash
          {7..0}     # Brace expansion: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
       2**{7..0}     # Brace expansion: 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
       2**{7..0}&$1  # Brace expansion: 128&n 64&n 32&n 16&n 8&n 4&n 2&n 1&n (Bitwise AND)
     $[2**{7..0}&$1] # Arithmetic expansion
echo $[2**{7..0}&$1] # and output
```

Answer (score 12):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/), 35 bytes

```python
lambda n:[n&2**i for i in range(8)]
```

Little-endian with zeros at unused powers of 2.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpPzUhLK1MhLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDQjP2P0ioJLW4BCSqYWGmo2BkYqCjYKijYGaiacWloFBQlJlXogFSoaOgrmunrqOQBuZpArkxeeqa/wE)**

Answer (score 10):

## [Catholicon](https://github.com/okx-code/Catholicon/), 3 bytes

```
ṫĊŻ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sycjPyUzOz/v//@HO1Ue6ju7@/9/MFAA)

Explanation:

```
ṫ       Decompose         into the largest values where:
 Ċ               the input
  Ż       the bit count is truthy (equal to one)
```

Comment: Interesting! Get TIO'd :D

Comment: Works with 302231454903657293676544. Nice.

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires 0-based indexing (`⎕IO←0`).

```apl
2*⍸⍢⌽⍤⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/420HvXueNS76FHP3ke9Sx51LfmfBhR/1NsHUdLVfGi98aO2iUBecJAzkAzx8Az@n6ZgYQYA)

`2` two
`*` raised to the power of
`⍸` the **ɩ**ndices where true
`⍢` while
`⌽` reversed
`⍤` of
`⊤` the binary representation

Answer (score 9):

## [Sledgehammer](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer) 0.2, 3 bytes

```
⡔⡸⢣
```

Decompresses into `{intLiteral[2],call[NumberExpand,2]}`.

Sledgehammer is a compressor for Wolfram Language code using Braille as a code page. The actual size of the above is 2.75 bytes, but due to current rules on meta, padding to the nearest byte is counted in code size.

Comment: Huh! Neat little language, and all the characters are actually printable.

Comment: And now I can't get the Peter Gabriel [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJWJE0x7T4Q) out of my mind...

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ýo&
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179178/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

Contains zeros (including -loads of- trailing zeros).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Nx8tf//DU0B) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeXiCvZLCo7ZJCgpK9v8Pz81X@6/zP9pQR8FIR8HQFIjNdBTMTIAYyLYAso1MDGIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý      # Create a list in the range [0, (implicit) input]
       #  i.e. 15 → [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
       #  i.e. 16 → [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
 o     # Take 2 to the power of each value
       #  → [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768]
       #  → [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536]
  &    # Bitwise-AND each value with the (implicit) input
       # 15 → [1,2,4,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
       # 16 → [0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
       # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Comment: ... what?! Never honestly seen `bitwise and` used in osabie. Nice one.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I indeed also don't use it very often. Can't even find any other answer I've used `&` in. xD I have used Bitwise-XOR a couple of times, like [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177572/52210) or [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174075/52210) and Bitwise-NOT once [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/178998/1) (which I later removed again after golfing further..). I do use Bitwise-AND, XOR, OR, NOT, SHIFT, etc. pretty often in Java, but in 05AB1E not so much. :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 17 bytes

```
#~NumberExpand~2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X7nOrzQ3KbXItaIgMS@lzkjtf0BRZl5JdJqDiVHsfwA)

Mathematica strikes again.

Comment: This also works with input of 302231454903657293676544.

Answer (score 7):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 29 bytes

Contains 5 unprintable characters.

```cs
n=>"€@ ".Select(a=>a&n)
```

## Explanation

```cs
//Lambda taking one parameter 'n'
n=>
//String with ASCII characters 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, and 1
"€@ "
//Iterate through all the chars of the above string and transform them to
.Select(a=>
//A bitwise AND operation between the integer value of the current char and the input value
a&n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXouPpmleam1qUmJSTCuLb2SXZ/s@ztVM61OCgIMDBwsSopBecmpOaXKKRaGuXqJan@d@aKy2/SAOoViHT1sA6U1vbxsjU1FqTK7wosyTVJzMvVUOp2qDWSqG6WqHasFahtlZJRyFTR6G4pCgzL13PKz8zTwMooqSTpJGpqalpzfUfAA)

Comment: But we need to get rid of zeros, like `n=>new int[8].Select((j,i)=>1<<i&n).Where(i=>i!=0)` The part before `Where` is five bytes shorter btw

Comment: @polfosol `The output may contain zeros`

Comment: @JoKing Still, `n=>new int[8].Select((j,i)=>1<<i&n)` is 35 bytes long and we won't need additional flags and text encodings.

Comment: Using ascii characters 0-7 should be shorter, eg `n=>"INSERT ASCII HERE".Select(a=>1<<a&n)` But I'm on a mobile device that can't display or type unprintables, so I'll have to wait till I get home to update the answer

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>27</s> 23 bytes

```r
bitwAnd(scan(),2^(7:0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxNCsIwEIX3PcWAmxnQUEutIrrwIkJaEw3YSWmmtFJ69tgsdPM93g@vjxsYe91BaDSDY/GgwQ7ciPMMq3uZdwdigjh@AgbdGqg/YqDxAwtl9vob40RzOrns/olSiuZpibWT8cYPTDXStrjj8ZwTxSWzWB3WEzxViUWZJ9knVCXFLw)

#### Unrolled code and explanation :

```r
A = scan()         # get input number A from stdin
                   # e.g. A = 65

bitwAnd( A , 2^(7:0))  # bitwise AND between all powers of 2 : 2^7 ... 2^0 and A
                       # and implicitly print the result
                       # e.g. B = bitwAnd(65, c(128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1)) = c(0,64,0,0,0,0,0,1)
```

- 4 bytes thanks to @Kirill L.

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYxNCsIwEIX3PcWAmxnQUEutIrrwIkJaEw3YSWmmtFJ69tgsdPM93g@vjxsYe91BaDSDY/GgwQ7ciPMMq3uZdwdigjh@AgbdGqg/YqDxAwtl9vob40RzOrns/olSiuZpibWT8cYPTDXStrjj8ZwTxSWzWB3WEzxViUWZJ9knVCXFLw) with bitwise and.

Comment: @KirillL.: brilliant !

Answer (score 6):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 38 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int y=8;y-->0;Print(x&1<<y));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O@YXJKZn2eTmVdip5CmYPu/wtauOi2/SAMooFBpa2FdqatrZ2AdUATka1SoGdrYVGpqWtf@t@ZK0zAyNNa0/g8A)

Comment: [aw, close :P](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqPg6ZpXmptalJiUkwoSsLNTSFOw/V9ha4cQ1wtKzEtP1TDQsdDUC07NSU0u0ci0tatQM7SxydT8b80VUATUqJGmYWhipKlp/R8A)

Comment: Fails for inputs `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, `16`, etc. (the `x>y` should be `x>=y` instead).

Comment: @ASCIIOnly - I'm telling you, the [range operator](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23205) is going to be sweet :)

Comment: @ASCII-only Mean while, you can use the flag `/u:System.Linq.Enumerable` and try [this](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9Wmpdsk5lXoqPg6ZpXmptalJiUkwoSsLNTSFOw/V9haxeUmJeeqmGgY6GpF5yak5pcopFpa1ehZmhjk6n535oroAioWiNNw9DESFPT@v@//IKSzPy84v/6pVbBlcUlqbl6Ppl5hXoI0wE "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") for 31 bytes

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance sure. but i'd prefer not to list language as "C# `/u:System.Linq.Enumerable`" :P

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 39 bytes

```c
f(n){for(;n;n&=n-1)printf("%d ",n&-n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOi2/SMM6zzpPzTZP11CzoCgzryRNQ0k1RUFJJ09NN0/TuvZ/WX5mikKJBlBGIU9ToZqLE0mVrR1QIVDYmosTZJw1QjImTwnIreUC685NzMzTAOst0bAwAykr0TAyMYAwDCGUmQmEBonW/gcA)

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOk9NraAoM68kTUNJNUVBSSdPTTdPUxsopZana6hpXfu/LD8zRaFEA6hEIU9ToZqLE0m5rR1QB1DYmosTZJg1QjImTwnIreUC685NzMzTAOst0bAwAykr0TAyMYAwDCGUmQmEBonW/gcA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>16</s> 12 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan*

```perl6
*+&2**all ^8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0tbzUhLKzEnRyHO4r81V3FpkkJZYk5parGGb6mCSpamQjWXAhAA1TuUWYOZunYKjnmVCirFCtVAMb2C0uIMKxCvVgOoHKIEpLSWiystv0jBwkzHyMRAx1DHzARsVHFipYKeWpqeGsQWoLr/AA)

Returns an All Junction with 8 elements. This is a rather non-standard way of returning, but generally, Junctions can act as ordered (at least until autothreading is implemented) lists and it is possible to extract the values from one.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
*+&              # Bitwise AND the input with
   2**           # 2 raised to the power of
      all ^8     # All of the range 0 to 7
```

Answer (score 5):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <strike>133</strike> <strike>110</strike> <strike>63</strike> 58 bytes

*58-byte solution thanks to @ceilingcat*.

```c
x=256;main(y){for(scanf("%d",&y);x/=2;)printf("%d ",y&x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///v8LWyNTMOjcxM0@jUrM6Lb9Iozg5MS9NQ0k1RUlHrVLTukLf1shas6AoM68ELKqgpFOpVqFpXfv/v5GJIQA)

Comment: In C89, you can declare like `main(){}` and the return type defaults to int.  Same for variables at global scope.  Also, at least on normal implementations like clang, printf and scanf work without prototypes.  You get warnings of course, but it's still valid C89 (maybe) or at least K&R C for them to be implicitly declared.  The types of the C objects you pass as args defines how they're passed, so a `char*` and `int*` will Just Work without truncating pointers to 32-bit on x86-64 or anything.  (Default argument promotions happen, same as for variadic functions which they are anyway.)

Comment: Or is this aiming to be valid C11 with no undefined behaviour?  If so, proudly proclaim it.  :)  And BTW, writing a function that takes an output array as an arg would probably be smaller.  Anyway, see [Tips for golfing in C](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203)

Comment: You can use bitwise `&` to check if a bit is set.  Like `y&(1<<x)&&printf("%d ",1<<x);`.  Or to not skip zeros, just  `printf("%d ", y&(1<<x))`.  Or instead of counting bit positions, use `x=256` and `x>>=1` to shift the mask.   `main(y){int x=256;for(scanf("%d",&y);x>>=1;)printf("%d ",y&x);}` 63 bytes  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XczRCsIgGIbhWxGh4T@U6aiInHYtYm0J5mIFqbFrtxp0UKcf7/dYZr0JQykX4wJJ8HThjqJqN1vZjxO5WRN6gldHTKsEMmqthITr9K6WGWGaqghyLk39eS7KF9nRRLP8Ix5n508kMqY5ZCW6LlKSWAat@IH8wBloYirDnssZjZMbXDAe1U1p1@IF "C (clang) – Try It Online") clang will even compile that with `-std=c11`

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P02jUqdCszotv0ijwtbQxsbYwLpC39bIWrOgKDOvJE1DSTVFQUmnUq1C07r2f25iZp4GULGGkYkhiA@kAA "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## 05AB1E, 7 bytes

```
2вRƶ<oò
```

explanation:

```
2в        convert input to binary array
R         reverse array
ƶ<        multiply each item by it's index and subtract 1
oò        2^item then round down
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6MKmoGPbbPIPb/r/39AUAA)

Comment: Also works with input of 302231454903657293676544

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 13 bytes

```julia
n->n&2.^(0:7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@z9P1y5PzUgvTsPAylzzf25igQZQpKAoM68kJ08jTSNPU1Mn2sJMR8HIxEBHwVBHwcwkVvM/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
(mapM(\n->[0,2^n])[7,6..0]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyM3scBXIyZP1y7aQMcoLi9WM9pcx0xPzyBWUVHzf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqChdn/f8lpOYnpxf91kwsKAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->n{8.times{|i|p n&2**i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6v2kKvJDM3tbi6JrOmQCFPzUhLK7O29n@0hZmOgpGJgY6CIZA2M4nVS01MzlCorqmoUSgoLSlWUFKurqi1UrJWSIuuiLUGi9X@BwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 6 bytes

```apl
2*⍸⌽⊤⎕
```

2 to the `*` power of the `⍸` indices of the true bits of the `⌽` reversed `⊤` binary encoding of the `⎕` input

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862hXS/htpPerd8ahn76OuJUCp/0DB/2kKXBZmAA)

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, <s>8</s> 5 bytes

```
Æ&2pX
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=xiYycFg=&input=ODY=)

```
Æ&2pX     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ         :Map each X in the range [0,U)
 &        :  Bitwise AND of U with
  2pX     :  2 to the power of X
```

---

### Alternative

Suggested by [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver) to avoid the `0`s in the output using the `-mf` flag.

```
N&2pU
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=TiYycFU=&input=ODYKLW1m)

```
N&2pU     :Implicitly map each U in the range [0,input)
N         :The (singleton) array of inputs
 &        :Bitwise AND with
  2pX     :2 to the power of U
          :Implicitly filter and output
```

Comment: Nice one. You can do [`N&2pU`](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=TiYycFU=&input=ODYKCi1tZg==) with `-mf` to avoid the `0`s

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
BPfqW
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3ykgrTD8/38LMwA)

## Explanation

Consider input `86` as an example.

```
B    % Implicit input. Convert to binary (highest to lowest digits)
     % STACK: [1 0 1 0 1 1 0]
P    % Flip
     % STACK: [0 1 1 0 1 0 1]
f    % Find: indices of nonzeros (1-based)
     % STACK: [2 3 5 7]
q    % Subtract 1, element-wise
     % STACK: [1 2 4 6]
W    % Exponential with base 2, element-wise. Implicit display
     % STACK: [2 4 16 64]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
Ýoʒ›}æʒOQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Nz8U5MeNeyqPbzs1CT/wP//DU0B)

---

This is also correct for 6-bytes, but it doesn't complete in time on TIO for 86:

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
ÝoæʒOQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ//wslOT/AP//7cwAwA)

Comment: Both your answers output an empty set for `15`, instead of `[1,2,4,8]`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen needed `2**0`, nice catch. `Ý` over `L`.

Comment: Ah, I know the feeling. Also had `L` instead of `Ý` at first in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

## TSQL, <s>43</s> 39 bytes

Can't find a shorter fancy solution, so here is a standard loop.
-4 bytes thanks to MickyT and  KirillL

```
DECLARE @y int=255

,@ int=128s:PRINT @y&@ SET @/=2IF @>0GOTO s
```

**[Try it out](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/973160/sum-of-powers-of-2)**

Comment: using the bitwise and (&) you can save a few with the following `,@ int=128s:print @y&@ set @/=2IF @>0GOTO s`.  This is hinted by @KirillL for the R answer

Comment: @MickyT that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

## APL(NARS) 18 chars, 36 bytes

```
{(⍵⊤⍨8⍴2)/⌽1,2*⍳7}
```

test:

```
  f←{(⍵⊤⍨8⍴2)/⌽1,2*⍳7}
  f 86
64 16 4 2 
  f 240
128 64 32 16 
  f 1
1 
  f 64
64 
  f 3
2 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>19</s> 16 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to ngn!

```
{*/x#2}'&|(8#2)\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWku/QtmoVl2tRsNC2Ugz5n@agoXZfwA)

oK does not have `power` operator, that's why I need a helper function `{*/x#2}` (copy 2 `x` times and reduce the resulting list by multiplication)

Comment: you can [omit the `{` `x}`](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWku/QtmoVl2tRsNC2Ugz5n@agoXZfwA)

Comment: @ngn Thanks! I tried it and it worked, but I wasn't sure it is acceptible.

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
{:T{2\#T&}%}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/2iqk2ihGOUStVrX2f12w1n9DAwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>41</del> 39 bytes

```php
for($c=256;$c>>=1;)echo$argv[1]&$c,' ';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFSSbY1MzaxVku3sbA2tNVOTM/JVEovSy6INY9VUknXUFdSt////b2EGAA)

Or **38** with no fun `>>=` operator and PHP 5.6+:

```php
for($x=8;$x--;)echo$argv[1]&2**$x,' ';
```

Or **36** with little-endian ("0 2 4 0 16 0 64 0") output:

```php
while($x<8)echo$argv[1]&2**$x++,' ';
```

Really I just wanted to use the `>>=` operator, so I'm sticking with the **39**.

Tests:

```php
$php pow2.php 86
0 64 0 16 0 4 2 0

$php pow2.php 240
128 64 32 16 0 0 0 0

$php pow2.php 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

$php pow2.php 64
0 64 0 0 0 0 0 0

$php pow2.php 65
0 64 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 125 bytes

```
_->In_x+128a+m
m+x+a->m+b
m+0x+a->n+a
m+0a->o+Out_b+Out_" "
n+b->n+x+c
n+0b+a->n+c
n+0a->p
o+b->o+c
o+0b->p
p+2c->p+a
p+0c->m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxCsMwDAXQ3acoWT8GN3TolL1Tj2Bsp9BAZRnigE8fRXYX6fG/UPil74e2vYp4u7yyb7jPzwAyhIZgF0JUuuGM0K1ivI/q45jTbTIZsdcNSeni/3hYVQz3mjVgLXtQMCfd@q/AqUjkcXKpG@dd7HoB) or [Test every input!](https://tio.run/##jY9Ba4MwFMfPzad4iK6V4NSMwtg67zt1h/Y2kJikUzAvmdohbPvs7mmh9LhL8uP/z/vxUsm@npQcdru1Qb2GApTT5l51OJVJ8YrlyHPxKLlllo9cJoXlFWG2MHI5M5Hj@/NQVssZQMCQV3M9ckWYVZfHCxN55ubaUeConAPPhaKbfJ5nRHaibRg7uQ4QGoRw05tPyCHM42fQjq32x8Pb8fASboyqHYQIP5A6P6SyVbWxTX9D1x/FbOW7BocTBNGDBogSIXqI@ncMZkMQfl@sTwn8UvIfdaKvdhDFXQ5Fqs1Xiue2pbGPznhIHGgzmM42SBONipl2aKZJbLd/)

#### Explanation

```
_->In_x+128a+m           # Initialize universe with input, 128a (value to compare to) and m (state)
m+x+a->m+b               # If c has been halved, subtract min(a, x) from a and x and put its value into b
m+0x+a->n+a              # If x < a, continue to state n
m+0a->o+Out_b+Out_" "    # Else print and continue to state o
n+b->n+x+c               # Add min(a, x) (i.e. x) back to x, and add it to c (we're collecting a back into c)
n+0b+a->n+c              # Then, add the rest of a to c
n+0a->p                  # Then, go to state p
o+b->o+c                 # Add min(a, x) (i.e. a) to c - x _is_ greater than a and so contains it in its binary representation, so we're not adding back to x
o+0b->p                  # Then, go to state p
p+2c->p+a                # Halve c into a
p+0c->m                  # Then go to state m
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 88 bytes (4×22=88 codels)

*My first Piet answer!*

```
taqu ci?aqtqqiarufqqrNdsssec ?a??q??vejraimMdk??e lane???nv??rr ?Mddtqe ll esufnvsbiesue
```

In grid form:

```
taqu ci?aqtqqiarufqqrn
dsssec ?a??q??vejraimm
dk??e lane???nv??rr ?m
ddtqe ll esufnvsbiesue
```

As a PNG:
[image: so small!]
And with larger codels:
[image: ah, much better!]

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJw1jtEKwyAMRf8lzxEa2xnrr0gfRueg0G0Ft6exf18SrcboTXLkfmF93QqknAekgBNekGYkyaJjKw1yJisE9DowWsEjL5jJ42ib2LC5Y5qjYnaTtqMg2pGPRFOD53OClQ06wCZiD1bYXl75Nt9hCTV3ssHaLGbMpJLiq1nvVV4WhFoOSOCcA4R9e8ibBluiS10h3a97LQjb8_i8pRsD_P5_tz8d)

In my best attempt at pseudocode:

```
n=input+1
p=256
while p>=1
  {p=p/2
  if n>p
    {n=n-p
    print p}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,p=1:n/p*[1]and f(n,p*2)+[p&n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCoMwFEbh3af4l1RjIzWpigj6IiFDigQFe72oi0@fptvhDB/f17KTiTGMm/9@Zg9SPOqBXlxa7TzNCEVapZFPyw9yMewHCCvB9p2CaWoFrdA1qdvWDRnAx0oXcvE@UU0QZw6BZPwhKeMP)

Comment: @JonathanAllan this definitely helped. Thanks for notifying me.

Comment: ...and the restriction has been lifted, so -1 byte :)

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>45</s> 37 bytes

```powershell
param($a)7..0|%{1-shl$_}|?{$_-band$a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVR01xPz6BGtdpQtzgjRyW@tsa@WiVeNykxL0Ulsfb///8WZgA)

Takes input `$a`, loops from `7` to `0`, each iteration performing a bit-shift left (`-shl`) to formulate the powers-of-two for each exponent. We then pull out those `?` (where) the number `$_` shares a value `-b`inary`and` with the input number.

*-8 bytes thanks to mazzy*

Comment: `1-shl$_` instead `'2*'*$_+'1'|iex`?

Comment: @mazzy Oh, good call. I forgot we're dealing with numbers that work with `-shl`.

Answer (score 3):

## C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler), 33 bytes

```csharp
n=>{for(;n>0;n&=n-1)Print(n&-n);}
```

Port of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript (ES6) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179177/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##RYwxC8IwEIX3/oqjQ0kxhbbWIsYWHAVBNwdxkJDSW66SpjiE@tfjaQeHx3t833F6zPSI4aAdDrRHci100ARqWt8NVihqc0VJ884ovVjWghKeag4qivjAPHQvGAMCEpB5cbnb3RcSSglrCcWGU0uoKw7vLe@yyufURwDLx/hIz8ntIF5hqv70PLkF/2AnFnm16MwJyYj4K@bwAQ)

**Explanation:**

```csharp
n=>{            // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  for(;n>0      //  Continue looping as long as `n` is larger than 0:
      ;         //    After every iteration:
       n&=n-1)  //     Bitwise-AND `n` by `n-1`
    Print(      //   Print with trailing newline:
      n&-n);}   //    `n` bitwise-AND `-n`
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 46 bytes

```java
n->{for(;n>0;n&=n-1)System.out.println(n&-n);}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVA9D4JADN39FS8OBiIQ8StGoruDOjgahxPQnGIhcGgMud@OPSRO6tBLr33v9bUXcRfuJbrWYSKKAmshqeoAklScn0QYY2O@wD2VEUKL6yA74JLu8FMooWSIDQgL1OQuq1OaWwEtBwH1FuT69u5ZqPjmpaXyspzZCVnUc1lC14FRyMpjwgqtUDPlxh6snWL0eX@AsN8GjLCZLjEHxQ/jcH@ofAdDByMH/oRj6mA65uB8xvlwPNAtG/hipLuirFRzdPuyWekXbFuqN@6DIo9P8Y/T9nRzKF2/AA)

Port of [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript (ES6) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179177/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                     // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  for(;n>0               //  Continue looping as long as `n` is larger than 0:
      ;                  //    After every iteration:
       n&=n-1)           //     Bitwise-AND `n` by `n-1`
    System.out.println(  //   Print with trailing newline:
      n&-n);}            //    `n` bitwise-AND `-n`
```

Comment: Breakthrough in Java: [**36 chars**](https://tio.run/##fZDfT4MwEMff91dceFiKg2bMuZiRkfhoovNhL0vmHiowU4QrKWVmIfzteAXU6MOaXHvXfr73o5k4Cz9LPjpZlEobyCjmtZE5vwkncS6qCp6FxGYCINGk@iTiFLY2BNhDzH75J1kZUG5IT@0fej/QZyUTEtA94EjRVhlhZAxbQNhAp/wI/ag5Kc1CjOYhTjfoB67iIkkYTn0Stl1odWX9lpNulPe5C@qT7YyW@H44gnCHsjaXrSlhDZh@2r4OxybwYOHBrQfBHdnKg9WSjPx78hfLeTuqAf4PWBtq1CZ60Fpc7B3rp7Frd6lMWnBieEltmByZ84hlbdbgzORV7KU2A/dDIY8ZIS4dV6Xkz5xX/Ba2/c@23Rc), by using [this rule](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/16236). Let's go back 5 years and golf all Java answers ever produced!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Hmm, although I agree that it's most likely allowed, I'll pass tbh. I have used that rule when the input is for example an array, and we modify the input-array instead of returning a new one to save bytes. But adding an additional empty List argument just to store the output in to save byte with `.add` instead of `System.out.println` seems a bit cheaty imho.

Comment: Kind of like how `Array.sort()` doesn't actually return anything, it just modifies the input. That seems legit. In C# you can use `void f(out int x)` or `void f(ref int x)` to return the result, but that doesn't seem to help w/ golf in my experiments.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 22 bytes

```
say"@F"&2**$_ for 0..7
```

if newlines allowed as delimiter

[22 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJwU1JzUhLSyVeIS2/SMFAT8/8/39DI7N/@QUlmfl5xf918xL/6/qa6hkYAgA)

[28 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYrPzNPRUknN7FAycFNSc1IS0slXsdAT8/8/39DI7N/@QUlmfl5xf91CxL/6/qa6hkYAgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes

```python
def f(x):n=1;exec'print n&x;n*=2;'*8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo0LTKs/W0Dq1IjVZvaAoM69EIU@twjpPy9bIWl3L4n@ahpGJgeZ/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## QBasic, <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```
INPUT n
t=2^n
WHILE n
IF t<=n THEN
?t
n=n-t
ENDIF
t=t/2
WEND
```

Here's a [REPL](https://repl.it/@pimsteenbergh/LimegreenTubbyBackup), slightly expanded to not break QB.js's compiler...

### How does it work?

```
INPUT n     gets the input
t=2^n       sets t to a power of 2, overshooting the first power of two
WHILE n     while we haven't fully deconstucted the input
IF t<=n THEN        if we found a power of two that is in this number
?t          then print it
n=n-t           and 'deconstruct' n by that amount
ENDIF
t=t/2       drop down to the next power of two and
WEND        repeat testing
```

**Edit** Saved 2 bytes, `while n>0` is equivalent to `while n`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript - 33 bytes

```
n=>[..."01234567"].map(i=>n&2**i)
```

## 32 bytes, Oliver's suggestion

```
n=>[...2**29+'4'].map(x=>n&2**x)
```

Comment: This appears to be 33 bytes, not 30. [You can save a byte with this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5aT0/PSEvLyFJb3UQ9Vi83sUCjwtYuTw0oVqH5Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI03DwkxTLy0zpyS1CKSmQlOTC1XeyMQAvwJD/NJmJmjy/wE).

Answer (score 3):

## SAS, 91 bytes

```
data;input n;length o $99;z=1;do while(n);if mod(n,2) then o=z||o;n=int(n/2);z+z;end;cards;
```

Input is entered on separate lines after the `cards;` statement, like so:

```
data;input n;length o $99;z=1;do while(n);if mod(n,2) then o=z||o;n=int(n/2);z+z;end;cards;
86
240
1
64
```

Outputs a dataset with a string representation of the binary values in the `o` variable
[image]

Explanation:

```
data;
input n; /* Read a line of input */
length o $99; /* Output string (max of 99 characters) */
z=1; /* First power of 2 */
do while(n); /* While remainder is not 0 */
    if mod(n,2) then o=z||o; /* If current binary digit is 1, append power of two to start of output */
    n=int(n/2); /* Move to next binary digit */
    z+z; /* Double current power of two to get next power of two (add it to itself) */
end;
cards;
86
240
1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Wolfram Language 58 bytes

```
Flatten[2^#&/@(Position[Reverse@IntegerDigits[#,2],1]-1)]&
```

---

`IntegerDigits[#,2]` returns the binary representation of the input, `#`, as a list of 1's and 0's.

`Reverse@` reverses that list.

`(Position[...,1]-1)` lists the positions of the 1's in the reversed list and decrements each position by 1.

`2^#&/@` 2 is raised to the power of (position -1) for each integer in the list.

`Flatten` removes nested braces.

Comment: The sort-order restriction has been lifted (also you may have zeros in place of unused powers of 2 now, if that helps)

Comment: @JonathanAllan, Thanks, it saves 6 bytes.  There are no zeros generated by this approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 116 bytes

```
_->In_a+c
0f+a+0d->d
0f+a+d->e
0f+g->c
0_+0f+0g+0a+0d->f
0f+0g+0a+d->Out_c+Out_" "+f
f+e->f+a
f+c->f+2g
f+0c+0e+a->a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcq9CsMwDATg3U9Rsh4CkUJH7536CEbIPw20SSHu61eRCXQ5vuNOXvos72XvZonifU0CDVwh4Ewxn3SVoUbRxwQnN/D5qeFfvT2@PSlGTpcJNVQUv0AcOjA3Fyu4QCiK2e362z592dbdKM8H)

Uses a different approach to the [existing Alchemist answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179327/76162). Instead of counting back from 128, we count upwards, which can then support any positive input.

#### Explanation:

```
_->In_a          # Get input number of a atoms
       +c        # And initialise the power of 2
0f+a+0d->d       # Divmod the input by 2
0f+a+d->e

0f+0g+0a+d->Out_c+Out_" "+f    # If there is a remainder, print the current power of 2
0_+0f+0g+0a+0d->f              # Otherwise, do nothing

f+e->f+a         # Reset the number to the division by 2
f+0c+0e+a->a     # While the number is not zero, restart the loop

f+c->f+2g        # And double the power of 2
0f+g->c
```

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 machine code, 12 bytes

This is a function you can call with the x86-64 System V calling convention, with this signature:
`void binary_placevalues_withzero(uint8_t out[8] /*rdi*/,  uint8_t val /*sil*/);`  or
`void binary_placevalues_withzero(uint64_t *out  /*rdi*/,  uint8_t val /*sil*/);` as a quick hack for making the output something you can print as one hex number for all 8 bytes.

It isolates the place values in increasing order into the output array, producing a result like `80 00 00 00 00 00 00 01` for esi = 129.

We start with mask = 1, and left-shift the mask by 1 until it overflows an 8-bit register.

```
nasm -l listing
    25 address   code bytes    global binary_placevalues_withzero
    26                         binary_placevalues_withzero:
    27 00000020 B101               mov  cl,1
    28                         .loop:
    29 00000022 88C8               mov  al,cl
    30 00000024 21F0               and  eax, esi     ; al,sil would cost a REX prefix 
    31 00000026 AA                 stosb             ; *rdi++ = val & mask
    32 00000027 00C9               add  cl,cl        ; left-shift the mask
    33 00000029 73F7               jnc  .loop        ; until it shifts out
    34 0000002B C3                 ret
```

An alternate version that **only writes non-zero entries** (thus producing an output array of length `__builtin_popcount(val)`) is **also 12 bytes**.  This needs `val` zero-extended into ESI to avoid `test` false positives, unlike the version that doesn't skip zeros.

`void binary_placevalues(uint8_t out[8] /*rdi*/,  unsigned val /*esi*/);`

```
    11                         global binary_placevalues
    12                         binary_placevalues:
    13 00000010 B001               mov  al,1
    14                         .loop:
    15 00000012 85F0               test  eax, esi    ; ESI must have its high bits clear, so high garbage in EAX doesn't matter
    16 00000014 7401               jz   .skip
    17 00000016 AA                 stosb             ; store if the mask matches
    18                         .skip:
    19 00000017 00C0               add  al,al        ; left-shift the mask
    20 00000019 73F7               jnc  .loop
    21 0000001B C3                 ret
    22
```

As usual, ISA extensions that let us save instructions cost more code bytes: **a BMI1 version is 14 bytes**.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BLSI.html and https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BLSR.html).  Very efficient, though: each of these BLSI/BLSR instructions is only 1 uop.

```
     1                         global binary_placevalues_bmi1
     2                         binary_placevalues_bmi1:
     3                         .loop:
     4 00000000 C4E278F3DE         blsi  eax, esi    ; bit lowest-set isolate:  n &-n
     5 00000005 AA                 stosb
     6 00000006 C4E248F3CE         blsr  esi, esi    ; bit lowest-set reset: (n-1) & n, and sets ZF according to the result.
     7 0000000B 75F3               jnz .loop
     8 0000000D C3                 ret
```

(If there was high garbage in ESI, this would keep going, storing `0` bytes when EAX held an isolated bit outside the low 8.)

If you wanted speed, with BMI2 `pdep` you'd use a 64-bit mask that deposited the low 8 bits at their corresponding position within each byte.  1 uop / 3 cycle latency on Haswell/Skylake, at the cost of a 10-byte instruction to create the mask. :P  But slow on Ryzen.

---

I'm *not* sure this is optimal.  I don't think manually implementing `n & -n` and so on with xor/sub/and and so on would be a win, though.

Comment: Hah! I wrote up a solution that did exactly that before I saw your answer. I pushed the results onto the stack, which was elegant, but meant I had to preserve and restore the return address (cost 2 bytes for `push`+`pop`) and also had to maintain a counter so the caller would know how many values to pop from the stack (cost 3 bytes for `xor` to zero + `inc` inside loop). Total was 20 bytes. That's about as good as it's going to get. All the instructions are 1 or 2 bytes. Might be able to shave off 2-4 bytes by taking a pointer to a pre-allocated buffer as an argument, like you did here.

Comment: @CodyGray: heh, that's fun.  If you pop the ret addr, `jmp rsi` is 2 bytes, same as `push`/`ret`.  But unbalances the return-address predictor stack, so in practice more instructions is better in this case.  I kind of glossed over returning a size for the versions that skip 0 elements.  The caller could pass a pre-zeroed buffer and treat the result as an implicit-length array (which works for my array-arg way, but not so much on the stack.  Well I guess you could `push 0` / `call`.  But yeah, I was glad to find a fixed-length version with zeros so I didn't have to justify that or `popcnt`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ʀE⋏
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgEXii48iLCIiLCIxNSJd)

```
ʀE⋏
ʀ    # Range from zero to the input number, inclusive
 E   # Calculate 2 to the power of each list item (vectorized)
  ⋏  # Bitwise AND each list element with the input number
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 11 bytes

```
2*8-⍸⎕⊤⍨8⍴2
```

Explanation on example of number 86.

`⎕` Input number: 86
`⊤⍨8⍴2` Convert to bits: 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
`⍸` Indexes of ones: 2 4 6 7
`8-` Substract from eight: 6 4 2 1
`2*` Powers of two: 64 16 4 2

Comment: This meets the specs of the challenge, but it appears that there may be unnecessary hard-coding here for the maximum number handled (255). [This APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179180/17216) manages to print the powers of 2 in descending order without a hard-coded maximum, in 4 fewer bytes. Does that work in the flavor of APL that you use?

Comment: @Deadcode At least in Dyalog APL that would be `⌽2*⍸⌽2⊥⍣¯1⊢⎕`. The behaviour of `⊤` is the reason why the other APL answers use the Extended variant

Comment: My solution written in classic APL with standard defaults and does not rely on specific dialect and/or ⎕IO←0 (index origin, default is ⎕IO←1).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 25 bytes

```
.+
$*
M!`(\G1|\1\1)*1
%`1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLVzFBI8bdsCbGMMZQU8uQSzXB8P9/CzMA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
M!`(\G1|\1\1)*1
```

Match as many powers of 2 as possible, and then an extra 1. This gives a total sum of the next power of 2. The regular expression is greedy (default), so tries to consume the largest possible power of 2 at each match. The `M!` then causes the matches themselves to be listed on separate lines.

```
%`1
```

Convert each line back to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
Ｉ⮌Ｅ⮌↨Ｎ²×ιＸ²κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEIyi1LLWoOFXDN7EAznZKBBKeeQWlJX6luUmpRRqaOgpGmkAiJDM3tVgjU0chIL8cKGyko5CtCQbW//9bmP3XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Includes zero values (+2 bytes to remove). Explanation:

```
     Ｎ          Input number
    ↨           Converted to base (MSB first)
      ²         Literal 2
   ⮌            Reversed (i.e. LSB first)
  Ｅ             Map over bits
        ι       Current bit
       ×        Multiplied by
          ²     Literal 2
         Ｘ      Raised to power
           κ    Current index
 ⮌              Reversed (back to MSB first)
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print on separate lines
```

Comment: Apparently the restriction on output order has been removed, which means that the first `⮌` can be removed for a 1-byte saving.

Comment: Nice. This also works with an input of 302231454903657293676544.

Answer (score 1):

## [Alchemist](https://github.com/bforte/Alchemist), 274 bytes

```bash
_->9a+In_x+s
s+a->s+b+c
s+x->s+y+z
s+0a+0x+b->b+d+m
s+0a+0x+0b->n+e
d+m->d+2n
d+0m->e
e+n->e+m
e+0n+b->d
e+0n+0b->h
h+m->h+u+v
h+0m->t
t+y+u->t
t+0y+u->f
t+y+0u->g+p
t+0y+0u->p
g+0p+z+v->g
g+0v->f
f+c->f+a
f+z->f+x
f+u->f
f+v->f
f+y->f
f+0v+0u+0z+0c+0y+a->s
p->Out_v+Out_" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc/BCoMwDAbge59ieP0phIGHXXrfaY8gVasOZhFsi/blu8SOXZrPP0ml9jMsbn3voZROm4fF03cHdrXDarOjx8A8hCcykyzoQK9NjxHrPyBOPJziTJsRd88iplMOnguPOpCXxbFKNha1yPyCiMSUhaAC/ylW0KXpiog1Y6upfGxqBm3ISNwQJxmdMHCBZWTBwYi18euftVDiW0AZNMiN8lq1afOKoUuQs7k1pdzb9gs)

### Ungolfed & Serialized

The algorithm is generating the powers of two from above, subtracting them from the input, check whether it's less or equal (output & decrement value in that case) or not and repeat while having enough copies of every value, to restore stuff (reading in Alchemist is pretty much destructive).

The "states" `s0X` can be merged, same with `nxt` without changing correctness of the program by combining all the zero-rules. The order of setting up copies or cleanup doesn't matter<sup>1</sup>:

```bash
_ -> 9a + In_x + s00

# Setup copies of x and a
s00 + a -> s00 + b + c
s00 + 0a -> s01
s01 + x -> s01 + y + z
s01 + 0x + b-> b+s1 + m
s01 + 0x +0b -> n+s2

# Compute power of
s1 +  m -> s1 + 2n
s1 + 0m -> s2

s2 +  n      -> s2 + m
s2 + 0n +  b -> s1
s2 + 0n + 0b -> s3

# Duplicate the power of two
s3 + m -> s3 + u+v
s3 +0m -> tst

# Check if it's below the value
tst +  y +  u -> tst
tst + 0y +  u -> nxt0                  # if not continue
tst +  y + 0u -> go + Out_v + Out_" "  # if not equal, output & continue
tst + 0y + 0u -> Out_v + Out_" "       # if equal, output

# Decrement the current value
go + z + v -> go
go + 0v -> nxt0

# Clear & restore for "next iteration"
nxt0 + c -> nxt0 + a  # restore counter
nxt0 + 0c->nxt1
nxt1 + z -> nxt1 + x  # restore current value (possibly decremented)
nxt1 + 0z -> nxt2
nxt2 + u -> nxt2      # clean up remainder of power of two ..
nxt2 + 0u -> nxt3
nxt3 + v -> nxt3      # .. and its copy
nxt3 + 0v -> nxt4
nxt4 + y -> nxt4      # clean up the rest of comparison
nxt4 + 0y + a -> s00
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVPLjtswDLz7K4gs0AfSBLKzl1720l566qEfEMiy0gi1JVePxNmfd0nK2ngbA4KpEWdIUaTs1VkPJsR5PsLuBb5K2MIPe5zwF4Soqif4pWMaQbnR6ADuBBNI24Gs8BidJLGy2eJSCywWvMZ9jftp2aJ5w/W6wILitHjUbgPthxUuWuLYbWgoi29uGFPUMLqr9phGxf4wsC6Zjc2QyBCSQkMeFvhjLEegn7B01mb2CspBw4FCfk9jb5TEoPF8Dwzx6qpwIKnsilbaXhjKsWOInPFZqz9gTmDixwCt7t2VhS6yT7pCJ8qAigGpsDIo7qCdooCH74lUrYv4KDYa@15NMPG3Q/NnisfL8t/AZkXUf5Psv4BLEYsKH/4XEnehB417Bu9EuGBaeT1oG/meKnlPdr4vJ/SK65LTy4C4lFtyxXotPWbjdYjOazg5Dxurp4gl1F5G4@ym4pJgo72Vh3oQEyok5ZJF7@In1O4FzZr2NaeQebkp17x1uvBpdCGYtr9BVy6lu89FRBSVhhBqnvJaTamPwrtYwMFBsjS2y72zbiLY7wtbFPqBkEOpEtuL3n7PY2dioFG8Fb@3Aj4T8szjtQAPmdCj0G0pvsJxkt4EZwuP37xM8zzXop53Xf0P)

<sub>1: The way to read it is like this: The first atom on the left-handside encodes a state (to serialize control-flow), the other atoms are counters which are replaced by the right-handside.</sub>

Comment: explanation pls

Comment: @ASCII-only: Done :)

Comment: btw pls compress debug output, i.e. `rule 100 times` -> `[rule] x 100`

Comment: argh i keep getting close (read: i'm terrible at this)

Comment: [145?](https://tio.run/##Lcu9CsMwDATg3U9Rsh4GYdqO2Tv1EYxjFxqofyAu@OmrSEkX6Tu4C5/4fuV168zezo/iB9ztnpBNhkt2zghYECWRpGIKBsIJOlQR1KKG57f7eNzpMpmqUykI6BSGWtRM062@f4q6TwKp0gKSnJndlX619bWWjW1yOw) m = halve, n = compare, o = restore x, p = refill d. a = value to compare to, b = value to compare a with to restore x, c = value to refill d with

Comment: also it would be nice to have better determinism detection, although it would probably be hard (better = counting rules that don't affect each other as deterministic)

Comment: [deterministic 145?](https://tio.run/##Jc07CsMwDAbg3acoWX8MxrQZs3fqEYxrFxKoHxAXfPoqkr1In9DLf8P@ScfZiJzentl12McakVSCjXpL8HgjcGW4yiqjw0@YoQIvZlW8fs2FEZfbooqs8gDDTKGLWVVV2ZU0W0P8R65EMSsR2bv5l9qOkk/S0V4)

Comment: granted, this takes advantage of the fact that max is 255

Comment: [137?](https://tio.run/##LcvBCsMgDAbgu09Reg2CyLZj7zvtEcS6wQqNBmrBp2@W6C7JF/78cU/fD25HZQ52eebQwN8fCdAg@GQXhAir2ImzydAgDriuAlEtInidNax9ztNsihb1IQnd321cYjKkfV0jJImoR8jsb@4qVLeSD7Zv/wM)

Comment: [better state change](https://tio.run/##LcsxCsMwDAXQ3acoWT8GY5qO2Tv1CMZxAw1UtiAu@PRV5biL9MTXj@/02mg/qkiwyz2HBj/fEsgQfLILIWJVO3U2GQ1xwJ0qiN0qxuNTw3rO6TKZ0ov9ISnd321cajLc@6xrhKwRj0jEX923cN1LPsQ@/Q8). EDIT: actually, [131?](https://tio.run/##RYwxCsMwDEV3nyJk/RiEaTtm79QjGMctNBDZhjiQ00e13EIX8d5DUljj@8XLVkW8ne7JH3DXWwQbhot2YgTMjalxMgkHwheoU0ZBUOv82Kuf@xyH0WQ91RyNrtHPSvuhhf6payMWcRc6c6lLTpvYp/sA)

Comment: [128?](https://tio.run/##Rcw9CsMwDAXg3acIWR8GYdqO2Tv1CMZxCw1EtiEO5PRRLbfQRXxPf2GN7xcvWxXxdronf8BdbxFsGC7aiREwN1NzMgkHwhfUlVEQNHU/9urnXsdhNFlPtR2NrtEvlfZDO1T@U2piEXehM5e65LSJfboP) can probably be golfed more

Comment: Order doesn’t matter, idk if that helps

Comment: Also wait they’re broken

Comment: Yeah 137, fix for 128 makes it [138](https://tio.run/##PY2xCsMwDER3f0XJehjcQEOn7Jn6CcZxCw3UtiAu5OujSE7pIr076aTwie9XWtbK7O04Zb@hvw0RySSQHbU5Qh8FETCrFM4mY0M4wTUqIARVjR/f6udWu0tnikbVjkbX3E@R3FBHHvynTigx34e9UF1KXtk@rwc)

Comment: I’m sure you can make yours deterministic the same way I did, chaining instead of merging clears and possibly restoring x every time you decrement from y

Comment: @ASCII-only: That's a rather different algorithm (and way better golfed), probably you should post it as a separate answer.

Comment: [134](https://tio.run/##Tc/BDoIwDAbg@56iIRgljTJJ8CLh7skXMCFjm4HEdRMw4eC7z6IcvKxfs/zr2qqxi1pNVbW1ZLZQgzrogWKzry/UzFiUJ41OOCz0vnaosGVLNgnCGRUDDVN@7RdxDXh9TU37PRNIhEfDlzgzJCuIgGuRZsmtkvz8EtZLy3KR/yTE3Q9A0BOku9E@QUJ6zM5gvAAIQ0/THZLNeCMelO6s7jykBG/IfZhy9dCddf34p9@CWSKMJxtjUZYf), still working on it, will post later

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 31 bytes

```
n->[2^i|i<-[0..n],bittest(n,i)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjBCkBAEAbgV/lz2q1ZLUkOeJFtFYWmNE3sRXn3xfH7dD7Z7Zo3DMjixlBP/HDvgi9LibRwSuuVjBDbmGfV4zYCN0JPlq9R/CiwGbGWELqWUDeeUBHaJtr8Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
BXdXB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3ykiJcLp/38LMwA)

#### Explanation

```
B    % Convert to binary (as a vector)
Xd   % Give a diagonal matrix with the vector on its diagonal
XB   % Convert each row of the matrix to decimal
```

Comment: Nice result with 302231454903657293676544 working.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
bRεNo*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/KejcVr98rf//jUwMAA) or as [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W@T8p6NxWv3yt/7WV9koKunYKSvaHNxzeq1P7P9rCTEfByMRAR8FQR8HMJBYA)

### Explanation

```
       # Implicit input n
b      # Convert to binary
 R     # Reverse
  ε    # For each digit d in the binary number
   N   # Push its index N
    o* # Compute d*2^N
       # Implicit output of list of results
```

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 41 bytes

```fs
fun x->Seq.map(fun y->x&&&pown 2 y)[0..7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv2fk1qikKZgq6DxP600T6FC1y44tVAvN7FAA8St1LWrUFNTK8gvz1MwUqjUjDbQ0zOP/a9pzVVQlJlXkpanoKTqqKSgAdJTku@TWVyioJGmYGhipKn5HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
(2^I.)&.|.@#:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F/DKM5TT1NNr0bPQdnqvyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagoUZjGVkYgBjmpn@BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->n{(0..7).map{|i|n&2**i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWsNAT89cUy83saC6JrMmT81ISyuztvZ/tIWZjoKRiYGOgqGOgplJrF5qYnJGdU1JTYFCWnRJbO1/AA)

Same approach as [Jonathan Allan's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179181/78274) answer.

Answer (score 1):

## JS, 103 bytes

```
m=Math;f=a=>2**(m.floor(m.log2(a)));x=prompt()*1;y="";while(x>0&&x<256){z=f(x);y=y+" "+z;x=x-z}alert(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ArnoldC](https://lhartikk.github.io/ArnoldC/), 609 bytes

```
IT'S SHOWTIME
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE N
YOU SET US UP 0
GET YOUR ASS TO MARS N
DO IT NOW
I WANT TO ASK YOU A BUNCH OF QUESTIONS AND I WANT TO HAVE THEM ANSWERED IMMEDIATELY
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE I
YOU SET US UP 128
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE B
YOU SET US UP 0
STICK AROUND I
GET TO THE CHOPPER B
HERE IS MY INVITATION I
LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET N
ENOUGH TALK
BECAUSE I'M GOING TO SAY PLEASE B
BULLSHIT
TALK TO THE HAND I
GET TO THE CHOPPER N
HERE IS MY INVITATION N
GET DOWN I
ENOUGH TALK
YOU HAVE NO RESPECT FOR LOGIC
GET TO THE CHOPPER I
HERE IS MY INVITATION I
HE HAD TO SPLIT 2
ENOUGH TALK
CHILL
YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFBa9wwEIXv/hXvlmu7EOh1bM9aw0oaVyPF@BiSY0mg/x@2I0NJ0u7exOiT3vek599v779eX65XqQ8GC7pVSTwE3jGFIlYTGWphRh52bTCuaIa24tuw@NpnBWTOKBIVc2xWSEXWbRBslGvfIrt0FISx5SlAz/jZ2KpoNlCe8YEGemLUwMnntnFh30yJZ6HKcb9lJv@YfT/9uIWN/xXw/OkCKtq6wdHHBTzbj@q6cvEzwQ0ghrRD8pNU6s4OR4f1fIZpYlhlShg5Z5/mgbO2JaBSvAwjT9TMr3hIWFTy0iOMdqyRybrV2GK0IHXo/F@BQPeU8h2lfMCzbt3us0FvfTxqVhS2laeKsxZEXWS6lSB3Sx9i89Fgjf7Jpy9BU5AYP@JG5ozKJUn2r5uv19Pj4/AH)

I apologise.

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (Perl / PCRE2 / Boost / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup>), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
x(x((?1))\2|)
```

Takes its input in unary, as the length of a string of `x`s. Returns its result as the list of matches (each is also a string of `x`s whose length is the value).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwEEWvYlVW7VHiJo6UDRO3rlS2rNjRyiooBUsmDXYQQSEsOQBH5CLBLZXYfM37f/Rn2tq7cnp@J9QjGdzxYe8IzTCiqjbr2/VyJIej5zSoHKslwkC0U6F1tuNMsDS83ocuxiYVMpVQv8y2zWz17@bRhytqAIk98BDb9167qoBBuzu5U1HzHV5u2AtSW6lzHKckgYGG@bz1tulO5RhfkXhGQu2CkZ@vb4a0UaxnPbX49mRdzSN/ZtRnjzD8rTLCFlwnsV5oERVwHEdjrm82xkw97zlfSYBt8QHTlIuiLH8B) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwEEX3OYVVWbVHSZo4aiPExG0qlS0rdrSyCkrBkkmDHURQCEsOwBG5SDClEpuvef@P/kxTWbMYn94ItUh6c7zfG0IT9CiLzfpmvRzI4Wg5dTLFYonQk9JI1xjdchazyL3cudbHKopFJKB6nmzryerfTb0Pl1QBEn3gzrfvbWmKDPrS3Iqd9Jru8HxDn5HqQp5iP4Uh9NRNp43Vdftbjv4VgSckVM8Y@f78YkhryTrWUY2vj9pU3PNHQm3yAP3fKiNsxsvQ18dl7BVwGAalrq43So0d7zhfCYBt9g7jeJEH2TwNRJDPg3zxAw) - Perl (test cases only)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLRatswFIbv8xSnQtQ6q@PEptlIFZObZaNQ2uHtri7CdZXYRJaNrJZA19s@wB5xL5IdJ90GvbCQjr7/P78O7qpuv1h2VQfcQQpswiCCzumNcrozRalFMIk@LJWqCuNV2TZdbbTLRY4yzyZ9EEJA35qKaqMHwHptfS@U@nJ5tVIKQ4iRLMlYjmpbq157wbrS6ei@KLfe0aJM3dSehcDOk/n5/OOnZD5jKEfr1glep1PJTbom9158//H58holPkO9Ftzc9t4ZbWmH4/guTVluGRLcP97TDZXDaTiOcdDrXWfaBy3YmIWES9KX7aP1g3aRkOiWDGid3skRwKGzfTtzu0gP97Q7O0N4JgAoAIgTwbfpYVhN4ctKFcYI7kLqPUxPF14EuyDkFkPeICJwfaRN0XulnaMueJKm37LVV3V9o1ZZdpPJN3d6Oeqyaoc3SaAxxBKGM3AbBfD79VdwJCmqLspK8IayQtEDf8IjGEAQ/R3QE8r/qfkWTk8pzD9uNUS5IPxdOtX0G3FQvry8@wOovN@JnRDLGDFPfuJ@Px0ns9kf) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbjpswEH3nK6aptNgB0pDV9gGHrNRPqPrQKhsh4jhgFYxljJLdbV77AfuJ/ZCmY9jNpVojGTxzZs6Zg7nWUcH58aNUvOo2AubrpmntJyMKsZ@UWi88XuYGMr1cQQpfR192u5/r2@7H4@P3b@XnXUmOe7In5D6m9GH2ix7p/4BRCGOdZjqImXdmkUhiRF4vPOSrgK8Jb1RroWdPkjq3vMyMaLvKtvMh5XSMFzdQ0@fWbpKEN52F@Rx8fPBVTyqhClsSyoywnVFgTSfYwZPKQp1LRSg8e4BLL5EbwUTTKF6lUwYdYm5nmYXGnVxB4T56GsRKVWBQd5b19VdKe6PACGzG3mJtLx92Zf5asW0MENf26dS2ELaSSpBhFKnCgYGyN5VuuRI1Rd9z20jSAyY8Q0WE0hBUHIJuWkwPma1UG@JHPmWnBirGrMN8SC@nSRLlgvfv9IWgxwcQU0iQ/NyrvwdjR6fEbjgtVRzEKwa1qFthSRuCv/edMPSixaQz91R/MkGmyrk8T1XMIAjk5cT91FsgTxRQlCMh/oPCkdC6mF3Bri6BdNsI/vx@GV2jLn9TVhihCV@HQM5XCsb0xmmN5OrdOEaNuLD04J3314uGQx6O02h2d/eXb6u8aI9R1fNmPe0/) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NTsQwDIX3PYWVTW36o6ZoNikVJ5gTlC5GmnYICm6VBNGRWHMAjshFSgyCDbvnZ7/P9nqNjwvf7vZ5XXyEcA2lny7TVj6FhTvwvVdK7RtuiPea6KF9oz05gzaVHjuwfZPNiwcHliVch3i2bDJwvavD6mxEVSnKwM7gJkZHd60BN@ixd0MzZiBhlrA/8WVCyxGlQeWP0iMVmhJPANbA6sUnqXvd/W5cXmL96m2cMESPTEUOn@8fuYwJ//jNl6/q2fI5zXn0JahN3TCZf4wc8kI4x/TAiZHSEdWfTqfR3lTt4fAF) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>

This is a power of 2 regex that I came up with just for this challenge. It's possible that nobody has ever seen this before, and either way it will be useful in other challenges (so far, [Number of binary partitions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249404/number-of-binary-partitions/249432#249432)). It needs absolutely no context, and can capture a power of 2 anywhere within a unary string. It doesn't use any special feature other than non-atomic recursion and a standard backreference.

```
x            # match += 1
(            # Define subroutine (?1)
    x        # match += 1
    ((?1))   # \2 = match made by recursive call; match += \2
    \2       # match += \2
|    # or
             # Match nothing, causing a cascading pop to the top level of
             # recursion, ending the match.
)
```

Note that while `((?R))\1|x` (10 bytes) would theoretically greedily match powers of 2 with the same end result as the 13 byte regex presented above, regex engines throw an error instead of running it because the recursive path doesn't consume any characters before calling itself. Regex is designed to be guaranteed to halt in finite time, thus is given this rule much like the one where any loop with no upper limit on its iteration count will exit after making a zero-width match. So all the methods of matching powers of 2 using recursion or nested backreferences are stuck with using \$1+2+4+...+1\$ instead of \$1\times 2\times 2\times 2\times...\$

Also note that the non-atomic recursive regex presented above is not to be confused with the PCRE1 atomic recursive regex `^(x(?1)?x|x)$` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPbbtpAEH3nKya0CetgIrtIVWXjRGlK1QeaVIhIrQi1XLOGVc3aWq8LSeDXS2d37cS5SLX8sJczZ86cmY3zvLeI4/0bxuO0nFMY5LGgJ8vTVryMBIT5dAYBjNsf1@vfv/rlj9vb75Pl@/WS7H@SDTlzrbPNdmO93VvPAW0bjvMgzLuu33okL@ScZYq9eSQYXzw9Yxme0mj1EnfaYlxCjksZUiEyQeKMFxK02uMVLYpoQa17zON5MQJgMIDqVC31OeXz1AdBZSk4uP5OU64ixokF9y3AL59itpRykls9dxY4PpSI6b8LJWRqpwIWuNBgzWnU4UVeSh@Uh3AsqA9NdSgnl8JEC1qUqTRrVUeSFFTakJUS0y7k0txkf2gsMzHtz0wqZA00eRhnq5yllOQ2fLsYD8NPV5Pz0Qi2Znc9@fzBhiOT0CzqDI5lqFgC5EBQq/Yh0Z4mBKtBtA1tRaSlCYhQiQ6Hw7kHh8UNx@42OE2eijjBAKLE3ymntDkLKlPGKTFdYdw2Plk@Ytzacy0Kw7iDNUYyY0SDTuIQvSWWZQN3bcizAq/NTcL4nHR6nSqx@rirDELMQdDsi@dxdXj2Ci90Nb4LKMTD5I9cpmkqHadrs5tyt@vOfJyoFRZOChs6m44ShqUUeDkLGvEPRrCAq5kZBNz1odtlzYpNV9Us1J2lGxoTQW24vB6NbMAcDLum/2ocbOg3Sq6bWbGcBuDAdluTog96Iobj8dU4vLz6ej65@PJcQE1xZwE6oyolnRveMf3xX0BNG3FU1Yti/qtUVfoBijk6@o@YJ3xtD4Zq6NpPeXevO9aw2yB2LT2ynhlFQSkqsR4ee/XqWru903Ndx/kbJ2m0KPa9VFn/Dw)), which can't be adapted to match the largest power of 2 that fits in the available space, because unless it matches exactly the entire string, it ends up matching seemingly arbitrary powers of 2. And to work on any other engine besides PCRE1, it must be modified, either as `^(x(?>(?1))?x|x)$` or `^x(x(?1)?+x|x)?$` to be explicitly atomic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdS8MwFH3frwgh0FyXbm2ZyshKX1QYiA/q2zpDV9O12KUhzaAw/e31dvjkQy7365xzc2xtx01ma0uYIymhS0oWxDp9VE7btig1D5aLm0ypumi9KruTbVrtcp6DzF@XfSBIgK/CpjrqacF4bXzPlXraPj8qBYLEgJRILGeNaVSvPae2dHpxKMov7zCotjk1ngpCV8l6tb67T9a3FOSs6hxnTRpJ1qYVsvf87f1h@wISLqSpOGt3vXetNphBGO/TlOaGAi735wNOsC0iEcYw4fVg2@5TcxpSgesS8WV3Nn7CbhIE7ZAAY7SXM0KuyuavZmaTXueYzeeA0oRfHToVvqw5cwLFJrt04XkwBIIZACCX6cQGdFl3012S4FdiSaaaMCN/UObnn60c5Pgx8IFnMWTz4XuAjI1jFCZxFP0C)

## Regex (<sub><sup>PCRE2 /</sup></sub> Ruby), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
x(x(\g<1>)\2|)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLRTtswFIbv@xQHyyI@I02biA4VN@NmZUKaYMp2R5AVgttEdZzIMagS43YPsEfci3QnLWMSF7Hs4@//z@@jdFW3W1x0VQfcQQpswiCCzum1crozRalFMIk@XChVFcarsm262miXixxlnk36IISAvhUV1VoPgPXa@l4odXn1dakUhhAjWZKxHNW2Vr32gnWl09F9UW68o0WZuqk9C4GdJvPT@cezZD5jKEer1glep1PJTboi9158//H56holPkO9Etzc9t4ZbWmH4/guTVluGRLcP97TDZXDaTiOcdDrbWfaBy3YmIWES9KX7aP1g3aRkOiWDGid3skRwL6zfT1zu0j397Q7OUF4JgAoAIgjwTfpflhN4ctKFcYI7kLqPUxPF14E2yDkFkPeICJwfaBN0XulnaMueJSm37LlF3V9o5ZZdpPJV3d6Oeqyaoc3SaAxxBKGM3AbBfDn1@/gQFJUXZSV4A1lhaIH/oQHMIAg@jegJ5T/U/MNHB9TmDduOUQ5J/xdOtX0a7FXvry8@wOovNuKrcjXi/gT5slP3O2m42Q2@ws) - PCRE2
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BSsNAEEDvfsUYxOxKMiSBXtyuUKhXD@ItKUu023RhO102CY2oVz/AT/RH4iaVHucxb@b5/vV99CDhWTd6cEj6BOvVywq9rrcCjMwEnPbGarCy0V0b0A5smeYbKaOKIhG4LTPEtNgI0LSdAbbOmo7FaczPAlpNTbdnfFmEhTLYQToLVwC7owcCQzBB7I7KsDzjiNPiZZwPmesQ5PrQMb8yMhfgvKEOKInh9/sH4oRFQ3RHfBI19Qd2377VlIDneKjdx83tpeXrP3iKUOrxaa3UOLCBVc0yf@BV8cnHMUuLxeIP) - Ruby**

This is a straight port of the 13 byte recursive regex to Ruby's subroutine call syntax.

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl /</sup></sub> PCRE / .NET), 16 bytes

```
x((?(1)\1\1|x))*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwEEX3PYVVWbWHJG1cKRsct6lUtqzYkcoqKAVLJg12EEHBLDkAR@Qi6TSA2HzN/5r585rK2Wx4eiPUSdLb4/3eErqQaFW@3dxsVmFyODpOvUplvpLQE3NAB33jTN2SaVlPZSCFVb6xpuUsYbF/ufMtnug4EbGA6vm8tP5PU8zhkmqQ5y6PH/eusPkS@sLeip1CTXcyTAgZP5vfgJpcjQs4RRH01M9mI8TIgIBC/jBRM2fk@/OLSVor1rGOGvn6aGzF0X8sqFs8/OEzwua8iLA@KRJUkCEEra@ut1oPHedrLqAUpXjvAC6GIU2WWXYC) - Perl
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTRbtowFH3nK26ZWhwIFSnqNGHSqus67YG1E6LSJkARDQ5YDU7kmEFbeN0H7BP3IWPXcZKGttKCRGzf63POPb6xH8fNme/v3nHhh8spg27sS3Y8P6v484kELx6OwYV@9eNqdX/XXv54ePg@mL9fzcluTcg5cayRM3I2a8uq76yXOVUb6rHrxQ2HVp7xEzXlkSYoL0kuZvtrPMJVNlm8zjurcKEgxqHymJSRJH4kEgWp4PqCJclkxqwn5Ol0fEyAbheyVT1M15mYhhQkU0spwKHbFHIx4YJY8FQBfOIhsoVMkNhqOmO3RWGJOe0TT0GkZ3rDDAdpcopp1GEgXioK2kaoS0ahrA7lxEqa3ZIly1CZsa4jCBKmbIiWCmlnam4i0U/mq0gO22NDhahuCu750SLmISOxDd8u@1fep5vBRa8HGzO7HXz@YMORITSDnKFlGSgeADmQzMp9CFJPA4LVYLYNVQ2USpMwQSXpdjicduAwGQk83RKm4cmAA9xAtPhH7VRqzoypkAtGzKlwYRufLIo5Tu55Kgq3iRbWOFERJ2nSse@ht8SybBCODXGUYNhEAi6mpNasZcT6EY42CHMO3PK5dDpCL56/gQuNNL8BKKSD5M9Y5tA0nWArMxsKp@GMKXbUAgsniQ21dU0Lw1ISDI7d0v7CCO4K3TNdVzgUGg1erjg/ikcLUJQmIbWRqBlrMvt87ArdvFz/VeHPr99VugdQMGWn5EKL0pcspn901@U9xNbMJ5LZcH3b69mA1XAbij6x8@6zoW3RV1BadAZ3hnyw2eToaH3ahFf9/k3fu775ejG4/PKWmuLjyQus4Q9fedc7Y2gWk9aYvglQ0tFFGUdH/5Oxx1iFK93hVQp3eN/c413wEn8LLExYFn4VLQx/1ryftA9Y@F9qE5OxraSfWsd8QpIxLMoqLqnstqhsd63myenpXz8IJ7Nk1wz1Of4D) - PCRE1**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLRTtswFIbv@xQHyyI@kKZNRUHFjXqzDiFNMGW7I8gKwW2iOk7kGFSJcbsH2CPyIuWkZZvERSz7@Pv/8/sobdnu5ou2bIE7SICNGETQOr1WTrcmL7QIRtHJQqkyN14VTd1WRrtMZCizdNQFIQT0raio1roHrNfWd0Kpr9fflkphCDGSJRnLQWUr1WkvWFs4HT3kxcY7WpSp6sqzENjZZHY2O7@YzKYM5WDVOMGrZCy5SVbk3okfP79c36DEF6hWgpu7zjujLe1wGN8nCcssQ4K7pwe6oXI4Docx9nq9bU3zqAUbspBwSfqiebK@184nJLojA1rH93IAsO9sP87czpP9Pe1OTxFeCAAKAOJI8E2yH1ad@6JUuTGCu5B699PTuRfBNgi5xZDXiAhcH2iTd15p56gLHiXJ93R5pW5u1TJNb1P54U4vR12UTf8mCTSGWEJ/Bm6jAN5@/wkOJEXVeVEKXlNWyDvgz3gAAwiivwN6Rvk/Nd/A8TGF@cct@yiXhH9Kp@puLfbK19dPfwCVd1shFiLGLM7iX1vEk91uPJxMp@8) - PCRE2
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BioMwEEB/JYQBk7oRLfRSCS3suV9gPYg7rYE4kZiitPW6H7CfuD/iWmF3j2@Yebzp3IC@b9DaGbwuPF5xLPd7wkEco3kU4iAyec7O2XOUcjNHxzf@7trOWPzgMoe7TvOL81jVjQDLDDEw1N2CfEClwaq@syZwxXNzEVAltbtRUDaw7Wsh1lAVaTktAgGkC0OhXCc5kLL4y9mL43i5aDX45FSFusFeRGO0AZKr@S4fgzcBVeP6MC1VWf7PTJFb/rGGkHEg9v35xUD8Vddrdbvo68QiXUMzST5Nc6q2u90P) - .NET**

This power of 2 matching is based on the regex `^(\1\1|^x)*x$` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9swDHzvr@CMDZGSVLX7ONUYtmEDBqzb0D6mKaDYcqJWpj1Jbpx2/e0Z5XgfBeIXmuTpqDvxTj2o07vyfm/qtnEB7igXphFTCf9XumDs0ZrTa91T56TtVtYUUFjlPVwqg/AEY80HFSg8NKaEmjrsOjiDa1Bu7RdLDmHjmq2HT32h22AaOnkC8NlYDVWOejv8skQUTakF9RMuP3RVpZ0ur7QqtYPVAHtZZH9OjmnFuRzn@nmQ203kZ8znK9Kgyq8GNeP8VY6dtdxUzAv9s1PWs@RsOp0mnD@9hB4YGAtHCZ6IIfxlIIIzYlgR7l76WT65wUmMQT4fas8/VAjaIbh8/CO1dRsHeC7JjVXTWK0QHvOKGLWE60IhknSDbRcgh6h2rLHrnQ@6Fga5hFHnABMb5b/pPtA1B4sBRkMs3Z04DiAkxChx7C@WYKkdUcK31gSWnNIjED4AptT5goHWwIlWOa8pYXaRLvkcMDvaFFbjOmwuzuEdRCS8pZAtibHYKLdY9qOeIcNsKeG9c2rnRWWsZf180k8GUwCqxkVtdI0cUwl4kWNGYTYjgZcqFBtyqCY2J@pDxobNRVrwj0R@2Bixdapl44iiaXffqyuFa02T0jlyHpVWwGoajyV5F9/2kY8mN@TY1pmgWXxULh/z4Lr4Pv/aLXkYKpa88QlZwuVz/E7iVu1v2U12k/267fm0f72Pa7JPT8@zNP0N)), which uses nested backreferences. But since it must be able to start its match anywhere inside the input, it can't make use of the `^` anchor. A `(?(N)set|unset)` conditional is used instead, to ensure the first iteration is seeded only once.

```
      # tail = input number; no need to anchor, as all positive inputs match
x             # tail -= 1; head += 1
(
    (?(1)     # Only allow the second alternative to match on the first iteration,
              # when \1 is unset, and the first alternative to match on every
              # subsequent iteration.
        \1\1  # \1 *= 2; tail -= \1; head += \1
    |
        x     # \1 = 1; tail -= \1; head += \1
    )
)*            # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum 0
              # Return match = head
```

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl /</sup></sub> Java <sub><sup>/ PCRE / .NET</sup></sub>), 18 bytes

```
x(\1\1|(?!\2)x())*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwEEX3PYWprNomcRNHyoaJ21QqW1bsSGUVlIIlkwY7iKBglhyAI3KR4AYQm6/5XzN/Xltbk4@PrwhbQIM53u0NwgkEK4vt5nqz8rPD0VLsZArFCtiA9CE4NrRWNx2aV80cPCqNdK3RHSWcxO751nXhRMVcxILVT6el9X@ahpxdYMXg1OXCx70tTZGxoTQ3YieDpjvwM4Smz/o3wLqQ00KYoogN2C0WE8TEEAAF/DBhvSTo6@OTAG4k6UmPNbw8aFPT4N8TbJP7P3yCyJKWUajnJQ/KwHuv1OXVVqmxp5WoxBtdn1UZ6ylj5@OY8izPvwE) - Perl
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNLbtswEN3nFBMBgUl/GDtANlXUoA1aoECSFsnS9oKWKJsORarkKJaTZtsD9Ii9iDuS1aYBrM1oPnyc92a4lo9ytM4edroonUdYky@0E/0Y/o9UqM3BmFdLVR/MBPRKFuLKGaNSdD7ER2W1MDqF1MgQ4EZqC8/QxQJKJPPodAYFZdg9em2XIP0yTOcccOXdJsCnOlUlakcnjwA@a6MgT6zatL8sEqnLlKB8xOOPVZ4rr7I7JTPlYdGWvQ2yvyc7N@c87u4NQ4w3qwafsZAsiKfMrrVVjPPjxFbGcJ2zINT3SprAotN@vx9x/vy2dI/AGB4EeCYE/IdAAKeEsKC6hzgMkt7M9hqL8cs@9vJNIipvwSfdH7EtyuaCwGNSY@GcUdLCU5IToorhPpXWEnVtywohgYZtF2P324CqENryGDqebZlYyXCraqQ2W4kBOkEM9U4Y@yJLFR3FLj@dg6F0UyVCaTSyaERDoHoEO6bMF4u0Kl6U0gdFDjPT8ZwPwU4OJoVRdomrizO4hKYS3pGZzAkxXUk/ndcdn9azk3kMH7yX2yBybQyrh72614oCkDvfcKM2EjuOwV4kdkJmMCCCNxLTFSlUEJoXxd5j7Q5begRXBL7fGLHxsmTdFakrt1/zO2mXim4aDy3nDdOcPfFOVkcabbxGxZox8vgpQV81E3lNl6Qa5iw6yeD3z19wEiLSYtipKdaOnkAEFCtoc0JlMDBODZas8KP3UTQgK5beVSWF91LRxDi11r429vrqBLprHZp5UpMv9B01u7qr2Wwym/xgl8ezM15Ttr9rNnA3Hp2dn/8B) - Java**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTRbtowFH3nK26ZWhwIFSnqNGHSqus67YG1E6LSJkARDQ5YDU7kmEFbeN0H7BP3IWPXcZKGttKCRGzf63POPb6xH8fNme/v3nHhh8spg27sS3Y8P6v484kELx6OwYV@9eNqdX/XXv54ePg@mL9fzcluTUbOyNmQ84PRibUmllXfWS@zqjbUY9eLGw6tPDMkasojTVFeklzM9td4hKtssnidd1bhQkGMQ@UxKSNJ/EgkClLJ9QVLksmMWU/I0@n4mADdLmSrepiuMzENKUimllKAQ7cp5GLCBbHgqQL4xENkC5kgsdV0xm6LwhJz2ieegkjP9IYZDtLkFNOow0C8VBS0kVCXjEJZHcqJlTS7JUuWoTJjXUcQJEzZEC0V0s7U3ESin8xXkRy2x4YKUd0U3POjRcxDRmIbvl32r7xPN4OLXg82ZnY7@PzBhiNDaAY5Q8syUDwAciCZlfsQpJ4GBKvBbBuqGiiVJmGCStLtcDjtwGEyEni6JUzDkwEHuIFo8Y/aqdScGVMhF4yYU@HCNj5ZFHOc3PNUFG4TLaxxoiJO0qRj30NvscdsEI4NcZRg2EQCLqak1qxlxPoRjjYIcw7c8rl0OkIvnr@BC400vwEopIPkz1jm0DSdYCszGwqn4YwpdtQCCyeJDbV1TQvDUhIMjt3S/sII7grdM11XOBQaDV6uOD@KRwtQlCYhtZGoGWsy@3zsCt28XP9V4c@v31W6B1AwZafkQovSlyymf3TX5T3E1swnktlwfdvr2YDVcBuKPrHz7rOhbdFXUFp0BneGfLDZ5OhofdqEV/3@Td@7vvl6Mbj88paa4uPJC6zhD1951ztjaBaT1pi@CVDS0UUZR0f/k7HHWIUr3eFVCnd439zjXfASfwssTFgWfhUtDH/WvJ@0D1j4X2oTk7GtpJ9ax3xCkjEsyiouqey2qGx3rebJ6elfPwgns2TXDPU5/gM) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLRatswFIbv8xQnQtQ6rePEptnIFJObZaUw2uHtri7C9ZTYRJaNrJZA19s9wB5xL5IdJ90GvbCQjr7/P78O7qrusFx1VQfcQQpsyiCCzumtcrozRalFMI3OV0pVhfGqbJuuNtrlIkeZZ9M@CCGgb0NFtdUDYL22vhdKfbr@vFYKQ4iRLMlYjmpbq157wbrS6eihKHfe0aJM3dSehcAuk8Xl4t37ZDFnKEeb1glepzPJTboh9158/fbx@gYlPkO9Edzc9d4ZbWmHk/g@TVluGRLcPz7QDZXDWTiJcdDrfWfa71qwCQsJl6Qv20frB@0yIdEdGdA6u5cjgGNn@3rmdpke72l3cYHwTABQABBjwXfpcVhN4ctKFcYI7kLqPUxPF14E@yDkFkPeICJwfaJN0XulnaMuOE7TL9n6St3cqnWW3Wby1Z1ejrqs2uFNEmgMsYThDNxGAfz@@Ss4kRRVF2UleENZoeiBP@EJDCCI/g7oCeX/1HwHZ2cU5h@3HqJ8IPxNOtX0W3FUvry8@QOofNiLPM7jH2I1zhPcC8Tzw2E2SebzPw) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BaoQwEEB/JQ0DJmsjurCXldCFnvsF6kHs7BqIE4lZlN167Qf0E/sj1hXaHt8w83jTuxH90KK1C3hdeLzgVB2PhKM4RcskyqzMPsTLU7mXk5Byt0SnZ/7qut5YfOcyh5tO87PzWDetAMsMMTDUX4O8Q63BqqG3JnDFc3MWUCeNu1JQNrD9YyHWUBdpNa8CAaQLQ6HaJjmQsvjL2YPjeL3oNPjkrQ5Ni4OIpmgHJDfzTd5HbwKq1g1hXquy/J@ZIrd@ZA0h40Ds@/OLgfirbrbqbtU3iUW6hHaWfJ6XVO0Phx8) - .NET

This is a port of the Perl/PCRE/.NET version, to regex engines that lack conditionals. An empty capture `\3` is used to keep track of whether the loop has finished its first iteration.

```
            # tail = input number; no need to anchor, as all positive inputs match
x           # tail -= 1; head += 1
(
    \1\1    # This can only match on iterations other than the first, since \1 is
            # unset on the first iteration; \1 *= 2; tail -= \1; head += \1
|
    (?!\2)  # Only allow a match on the first iteration, when \2 is unset.
    x       # \1 = 1; tail -= \1; head += \1
    ()      # \2 = 0
)*          # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum 0
            # Return match = head
```

## Regex (.NET), 19 bytes

```
(x(x?)(?<2>\2\2)*)*
```

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Returns its output as the list of captures on the Balancing Group `\1` stack, whose lengths represent the numbers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BboMwEEWvYlkjYYcaEaRsQmgidd0TEBaITsCSsZFtBErEtgfoEXsR6iC1Xb7RzP9vBjOhdR0qtYItSostztXxqHFil2hlM5vPnJ1P2es1u2Z8x3drdHmhb6YfpMIPynO4F2l@MxbrpmOgiNQEpB5Gzx9QF6CEG5T0VNBc3hjUSWNG7YXyJHsuxAXUZVotIYCBLkqpfbVNctBC4S/vnxzH4aIvwCbvtW86dCyaox1oviXf@WOy0qPojPNLsNrn/0yENuElJTUSCpp8f34RYH/WzWbdJ6014@BCW9LUgx8tutDYJAp167uF02VZU5EdDj8)

```
(
    x         # \1 = 1
    (x?)      # \2 = 1 or 0; \1 += \2
    (?<2>     # Alias as capture group \2
        \2\2  # \2 = \2 * 2; \1 += \2
    )*        # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum zero
)*            # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum zero, on
              # each iteration pushing the capture onto the group \1 stack.
```

Unlike [Calculate the prime factors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104590/calculate-the-prime-factors/249917#249917), in this challenge, returning the output as a list of matches golfs better than pushing it onto the Balancing Group stack, even when we take advantage of .NET's ability to alias a capture group.

Without capture group aliasing, this golfs even worse. We can't use `(x((?(2)\2\2|x))*)*`, because when starting a new power of 2, `\2` is already set and the first iteration won't be seeded with `x`. And it's not just a simple matter of clearing the `\2` stack with a `(?<-2>)*`, because that attempts to loop a zero-width match and will stop after one iteration. So, patching this either results in the monstrosity `(x((?(2)\2\2(?<-2>)|x))*(?<-2>)?)*` (34 bytes): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9NboMwEIWvYqGRsEONCFI2IS6Ruu4JCAtEJ2DJ2JYxAiVl2wP0iL0IJag/u3mjN@99Y82Irm9RqQWcKBw2OJXHo8aRnsOFTpTmNGWX9JLS/MTTZ/Y@Mbb7mXO2W8LzU/BiOisVvgUsg5tIsqtxWNUtBUWkJiC1HTy7QyVA8d4q6QMeZPJKoYprM2jPlSfpwxAJqIqknNcACloUUvty22SgucJfvX/oKFovOgEufq183WJPwyncgWZb8o3dRyc98tb0fl6p9tm/Jlyb9UMlNZIANPn6@CRA/6jrjbqLG2cG269tcV1ZPzjs18Y6Vqgb384smOcl4enh8A0), or, slightly better, `(x((?(3)\2\2|x()))*(?<-3>)?)*` (29 bytes): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BboMwEEWvYqGRsEONCFE2oZRIXfcEhAWiE7BkbMs2AiVl2wP0iL0IJUhtl2808/8bo0e0rkMpF7B5abHFqTqdFI70HC50orSgB3ZJL@nHRBljO1o888MLK9huCc9PwavujZD4HrAMbnmSXbXFuukoSCIUAaHM4Nkd6hwkd0YKH/AgE1cKddzoQXkuPUkfC1EOdZlU8xpAQeWlUL7aJhkoLvGX9w@OovWiz8HGb7VvOnQ0nMIdKLYl39h9tMIj77Tz82q1z/6ZcKXX56RQSAJQ5PvziwD9s2426z5urR6MW9vipjZ@sOjWxiaWqFrfzSyY5yXh6fH4Aw) This is in fact comparable to [not](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/249432/4) even explicitly using Balancing Groups: `(x(?=(.*))((?(?=\2)x|\3\3))*)*` (30 bytes): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BboMwEEWvYqGRsKFGhCibICuRuu4JgAWiE7BkbGSMQEnZ9gA9Yi9CHaS2u/mjP/@/GcyMduxQqQ2sKCy2uFTns8aZXsONLvQiaBIxRunFj2XGlo/yWB4Zi1i0hdeX4NX0g1T4HrAc7iLNb8Zi3XQUFJGagNTD5NgDagGKj4OSLuBBLm8U6qQxk3ZcOZI9DbGAukir1QdQ0KKQ2lX7JgfNFf7qw1PHsb/oBdjkrXZNhyMNlzACzfbkO3vMVjrknRnd6qkO@b8mXBv/nZIaSQCafH9@EaB/1M1O3SetNdMw@rakqQc3WRx9Y5Mo1K3rVhas65by7HT6AQ)

## Regex (ECMAScript / Python or better), 27 bytes

```
(?=.*?(((x+)(?=\3$))*x$))\1
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NbsIwEIRfJY0qspuQQGjpgWA49cCFQ3sEDhYYx6njWLb5KT/XPkAfsS@SJoJKvaxGmpnVfAXdU7s2QrvYarFhpqzUB/usDVHs4L0x/nrUACcy6YU1TEkSTgHgGGGjl0@PiOGxOcu0DnsnTFz17oxQHDCxUqwZvHTjZ@x6AQ8ws6SfHXIhGYAkhtGNFIoB4gNROynxzIlMrJbCQRA3cbEFUIQnkinucpwMLhdh53QOgmhqLJspB3zRXyH@Gey/oSbpNB21NrrcVAd/pvZUio1nqOJs5PmRzLaVgUyMCctEFOG5JP7RTwzTjDoQmJTUrXMwzfJORzdYDlqINNM7Z50BEQXez9e3d9taYvutaBiLcXkfnRXt26Jp3xpBm73rclGs/tiu12vdjwfD4S8) - ECMAScript**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NTsMwEIX3PYVVjWq7@WlSlA2Om1QqW1bsSGUVlIIlkwY7iKDILDkAR@QiYRpAbJ7mPc3M@9rammx8eiNgBRnM6f5gCKwEWpnvtjfbjZ8dT5aBk4nIN4IPRB/R8aG1uunIvGrmwpPSSNca3TEa0dC93LkOT1QYpWHK6@fzUvGfJpjzS1BcnH85bDzY0uRrPpTmNt1L1GQv/IyQqVn/BqBzOS3gFAR8ALdYTBATAwKm4ocJdEzJ18cnFdBI2tMetHh91KZm6N9XYFcPf/iU0JiVAb6PygiVC@@9UlfXO6VGVsh4WTDG@oDjXF0A58sepUrHMYnWWfYN) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNLbtswEN3nFFOhgUl/GDtFNlXUoA1aIEDSFsnS9oKWKJsORarkKFYcZNsD9Ii9iDuS1aYB7IWH89HjvDfDtXyQo3V2v9NF6TzCmnyhnejH8H@kQm0OxrxaqvpgJqBXshCXzhiVovMhPiqrhdEppEaGADdSW3iCLhZQIpkHpzMoKMPu0Gu7BOmXYTrngCvvNgE@16kqUTv68gjgizYK8sSqTXtkkUhdpgTlIx5/qvJceZXdKpkpD4u27HWQ/f2yc3PO4@7eMMR4s2rwGQvJgnjK7FpbxTh/k9jKGK5zFoT6UUkTWHTS7/cjzp9el@4RGMODAE@EgP8QCOCEEBZUdx@HQdKb2V5jMX7ex56/S0TlLfikOxHbomwuCDwmNRbOGSUtbJOcEFUMd6m0lqhrW1YICTRsuxi7ewyoCqEtj6Hj2ZaJlQxfVY3UZisxQCeIod4JY19kqaKj2OWnczCUbqpEKI1GFo1oCFSPYMeUubJIq@JFKX1Q5DAzHc/5EOzkYFIYZZe4Oj@FC2gq4T2ZyZwQ05X003nd8Wk9O5nH8NF7@RhEro1h9bBX91pRAHLnG27URmLHMdjzxE7IDAZE8EZiuiKFCkLzoth7rN1hS4/gksD3GyM2XpasuyJ15eO3/FbapaKbxkPLecM0Z1veyepIo43XqFgzRh5vE/RVM5GXdEmqYc6i4wx@//wFxyEiLYadmmLt6AlEQLGCNidUBgPj1GDJCj/6EEUDsmLpXVVSeC8VTYxTa@1rYy@vTqC71qGZJzX5TL@jZld37CIR/QvGWD3gdJ69e8t5v6a/2WTXrOJuPDo9O/sD) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLbtswELz7KzYEEXFj@SE3buHShC91igBFUqi9RQGhqLQlmKIEigkMBLn2A/qJ/RF3ZactkAMXu8uZ2eGCbdkelqu2bIF7UMAmDMbQerPV3rQ2L4yIJuOLldZlboMumrqtrPGZyFBm6aSLYojobKipt6YHuGBc6ITWV9df1lpjDAmSJAnLQeUq3ZkgWFt4M37Ii13wFLSt6iqwGNjlbHG5eP9htpgzlINN4wWv1FRyqzak3olv3z9d36DEZ6g2gtu7LnhrHGU4Su6VYpljSODu8YFuqB1P41GCPd/sW9v8MIKNWExwSfyieXSh5y5nRLojAYrTezkAOE52rzV3S3W8p2w4RHgmAJABEGeC79RxWXUeilLn1gruY5rdb8/kQUT7KOYOY14jInBzQtu8C9p4T1PwTKmv6fqzvrnV6zS9TeWrOr0cTVE2/Zsk0BoSCX0N3I0j@P3zV3RCklWTF6XgNXmFvAP@hCdgBNH474KeUP53zXdwfk5m/uHWvZWPBH/jTtfdVhyZLy9vfgC1D2Kl6GsIIfZDpDx7xxEv9hSy5HCYjmbz@R8) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJLbtswEN3rFFO3iEh9XCtGutDHBnqEoosWtiHINC0RlSiComAngbc9QI7Yg9Qdyok/RSiAImfezHszHKZUWDJ2/Cgkq/sNh3Tdtp35rHnJ9@NKqZnDqkJDrhYryODb6Otu92s97X8@Pv74Xn3ZVeRI5tnYmxNC9j7F83L6iVJvj9syOtL/4aMAPJXlyo8S58IpkFLzopk5yF4DWxPWys7AoCWOm8KwKte862vTpSeXVeXN7qChz53ZxDFrewNpCi5@@GvGNZelqQhNNDe9lmB0z5ODI6SBphCSUHh2AJdaIDeCiaJhtMomCfSImd7nBlp7swGlPQw0iBWyRKPqTTLE3ygd2gaaY7LkzdYN8mFXFa8R21YDsWmfzmlLbmohOTmVImRwYqDJm0q7bIic4CsUphVkAIxZjooIpQHIKADVdug@ebZCbogbujQ5J5ARei3mQ3ZdTRxLa5y/kxf8Ae9DRCFG8kuuYSo8Syf57nRbyMiPVgk0vOm4IV0A7t61wrAXHTptc8/x5yaITNoup5mMEvB9cV3xUPUWyBMFFGVJiLuUWBK2LkpuYDdDIOw2gj@/X0a3qOtnykvNFWHrAMhlpMCjd1ZrKFbv2tGq@VVLD85lfx00LPJwnIT3Dw9/2bYuyu4Y1gNvPtD@Aw) - Boost
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NbcMwDIXvnoIQCpj0j2AlyMWukAkygeNDgNiNCpU2JBV1FugAHbGLuFKL9tIL8chHfnzLPdxm3m/mZZldAH/3lRurZz9zB047IcSGRy2LIyKuJUV93j8QFWssZ7VFv1dtrYYOjG6yaXZgwXDiSB@uhtsMrLbSL9YEFLWgDMwEdmS09LhrwfZq0LZvhgzSMadjd@GnEQ0HTAZVP0oNVCqKvAQwLSwuzSn1WnW/H@fXIN@cCSP64JCpzOHz/SNPa4l/@uaPcjJ8jUsOXQViFQVT@w@QQ14myCmmvzBSTFD/6ZiLtqbeHQ5f) - Python**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BaoNAEIbvfYqphLprdVBDLtkuIZBeeyi9aRDbbMzCZiKrEkvptQ/QR@yL2NWEXIaZn/lmPtu9fw4WJLyqSvU1kjrDZv22RqvKnQAtYwHngzYKjKxU27hoDyaLkq2UXk6ecLnJYsQo3QpQtJsCbGqjW@ZHPr8AaBRV7YHxp9QtZI520AW4A9ifLBBogjHE9lRolsQccVy8jdMhfe@E6s55TK@0TATUVlMLFPrw9/MLfsi83guIj6Ci7siWzUdJIViOx7L@mj3cXL6vwqNEUTy/bIpiYCuJwYox1j9y1@fzGedB70qeDEMcpYvFPw) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BaoNAEIZfZZEBd7UrmpJLZEmg5z6B8SB2EhfWWVk3KAle@wB9xL6I3QhtL8P8w8zHN4Od0I0dGrOCU5XDK8714UA48VO88qPKkiPnfE5F6M@vIEQyh3Iu1vj0Er3ZftAGPyJRwl3l5cU6bNqOg2GaGGgabl48oFFg5DgY7SMZlfrCoclaeyMvjWe750KqoKnyegkADqQqTb7eJiWQNPibi2dO03DRK3DZe@PbDkcez3ECJDbyXTwmpz3Kzo5@CVZF@Z@ZJBteM5qQRUDs@/OLAf@zbjfrPuDbzCBdfbeIaFnWXO72@x8) - .NET

In regex flavors that lack both nested and forward-declared backreferences, an entirely different method of matching powers of 2 must be used: `^((x+)(?=\3$))*x$` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc89b8IwFIXhv0IjBPeSJiQIdcA1TB1YGNqxtJIVLs5tjWPZBlI@fnsKQ6XOz5GO3i91UKHy7GIWHG/I7xr7TT@dl5aOvVfSL60DOMn5eNR9ArQpwkKuJ33EUdvvRuMT5rF5i56tBsyD4Yrg6TGbIoogC3Gs2RCAkZ7UxrAlQHyQdm8MnrU0eXCGIwyzIQreAlipc0NWxxrnk8uFw0qtgKVTPtDSRtDvxQfiH9B/sPNyUc7ujLH2zTFZ2oMyvOl5ZTXNeklqxLbxIPhZkuA0xdth0ia5J0cqAmO@U7GqwSOew2DgbkkR7hWlcPsYor9NxPXaldm0LIpf)). This is dependent on ending exactly at the end of the string, so the capturing of the power of 2 is done inside a lookahead.

```
        # tail = input number; no need to anchor, as all positive inputs match
(?=
    .*?                  # Decrease tail by the minimum necessary to match:
    (                    # \1 = largest power of 2 less than or equal to tail
        (
            (x+)(?=\3$)  # Assert tail is even; tail /= 2
        )*               # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum 0
        x$               # Assert tail == 1
    )
)
\1                       # Return \1 as the match
```

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl / PCRE / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / Ruby / .NET</sup></sub>), 27 bytes

```
x((?=(\3)?)((?(2)\2\2|x)))*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwEEX3PYVVWbWHJG0SlA2Om1QqW1bsSGUVlIIlkwY7iKBglhyAI3KRMA0gNqP/v2b@vLa2JhsfXwm1ggzmeLc3hK4EWplvN9ebtZ8djpZTJ2ORrwUMRB/QwdBa3XRkXjVz4UlppGuN7jiLWOieb12HJyqMkjCB@um0VPynMeZwQRWIU5fDj3tbmjyFoTQ3yU7ijHfCzwiZPuvfgOpcTguoggAG6haLCWJiQMBE/DBRvWTk6@OTCdpI1rOeavHyoE3N0b@vqF3d/@Ezwpa8DLA@KiOcILz3Sl1ebZUae84LyatzKAAVT6FKq/StB4CzcYyjNMu@AQ) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTRbtowFH3nK26ZWuwSKgLqNBHSqus67YG1E6LSJkARDQ5YDU7kmEFbeN0H7BP3IWPXcZKGttKCRGzf63POPb6xH8eNme/v3nHhh8spg27sS3YyP6v484kELx6OwYV@9eNqdX/XXv54ePg@mL9fzcluTci5S0Ztek5xRFp01Bq1NmtK6fGOvkyvWnAcu15ct53KM1WipjzSXOUlycVsf41HuMomi9d5ZxUuFMQ4VB6TMpLEj0SiINV@vGBJMpkx@oQ8nY6PCdDtQraqh@k6E9PQAcnUUgqwnW0KuZhwQSg8VQCfeIhsIRMkpg177DYdWGJOu@UpiPRMb5jhIE1OMY06DMRL5YB2FI4lc6CsDuXESprdkiXLUJmxriMIEqYsiJYKaWdqbiLRT@arSA7bY0OFqG4K7vnRIuYhI7EF3y77V96nm8FFrwcbM7sdfP5gwZEhNIOcoUkNFA@AHEhGcx@C1NOAYDWYbUFVA6XSJExQSbodDqcdOExGAk@3hGl4MuAANxAt/lE7lZozYyrkghFzKlxYxifqYI6de56Kwm2iiTVOVMRJmnTie@gtodQCYVsQRwmGTSTgYkpqjVpGrB9ha4Mw58Atn0unI/Ti@Ru4UE/z64BCOkj@jGUOTdMJtjKzobDr9tjBjlpg4SSxoLauaWFYSoLBsVvaXxjBXaF7pusK24F6nZcrzo/ikQKK0iSkNhI1Y01mn49doZuX678q/Pn1u@rsARRM2Sm50HSclyymf3TX5T3E1swnkllwfdvrWYDVcAuKPrHy7rOgTZ1XUFp0BneGfLDZ5OhofdqEV/3@Td@7vvl6Mbj88paa4uPJC6zhD19519tjaBST5th5E6Cko4syjo7@J2OPsQpXusOrDtzhfXOPd8FL/C2wMGFZ@FW0MPxZ837SPmDhf6lNTMa2kn5qHfMJScawKFpcUtltUdnumo3W6elfPwgns2TXCPU5/gM) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLbtswELz7KzYEEXET@aXGLVya8KVuESBICrW3KCAUlbYEU5RAMYGBNNd@QD6xP@Ku7LQFciCxu5yZnV2wLdv9YtmWLXAPCtiYwQhabzbam9bmhRHReHS21LrMbdBFU7eVNT4TGcosHXdRDBGdNRX1xvQAF4wLndD68@XVSmuMYYokScJyULlKdyYI1hbejO7zYhs8XdpWdRVYDOwimV/M339I5jOGcrBuvOCVmkhu1ZrUO/Ht@6fLa5T4BNVacHvbBW@NowiH0zulWOYYErh7uKcXKseTeDjFnm92rW1@GMGGLCa4JH7RPLjQcxcJkW5JgO7JnRwAHDq715y7hTq8U3R@jvBEACADIE4E36rDsuo8FKXOrRXcx9S7357Jg4h2UcwdxrxGRODmiLZ5F7TxnrrgiVJf09UXfX2jV2l6k8pXdZocTVE2/UwSaA1TCX0O3I0i@P3rJToiyarJi1LwmrxC3gF/xCMwgmj0d0GPKP@75ls4PSUz/3Cr3spHgr9xp@tuIw7M5@c3P4DK@50QSyWyd7hEikSCWZIlP3c06dl@Pxkms9kf) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY89bsMwDIV3n4LQYjL@geUgi10hJ8gJbA8BYqcqVNqQVMQBMvcAPWIv4kot2qXbIx/fR3K5@@eZ95t@XWbrwd1dbsfruOYvbuYWrLJCiG1FPCrs93SkoLCmvu7rx0pEuy34nWwKObSgVZVMswUDmiOqdP6iuUnAKFO6xWiPohCUgJ7AjIyGnuoGTCcHZbpqSCCGOYbtma8javYYDcp/lBwokxR4EaAbWGzsU6yVbH83zm@@vFntR3TeIlOWwuf7RxrHIv/0zY8/lpPmS5izaHMQq9gxNf8YKaRZ5JzCA2dGCkcUfzqcRltV1IfDFw) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BSsNAEIbvPsUYxOyUZElWemm6lEK9ehBvSVmi3aYL22nYJDSiXn0AH9EXiZtUepv5@b@Zz3Wv74MDCc@60n3NSZ9hs35Zc6fLXQZGJhmcD8ZqsLLSbeOjPdg8TrdSBgUFmc9tnnAei20GmnZTwJvampaFcYgXgFtNVXtguBS@kHvaQxfgBmB/ckBgCMaQtydlWJog52Pxuk6HzK0XqjvvMb0yMs2gdoZaoCiE3@8fCCMW9MGMcAQ1dUe2aN5KisAhP5b1x9391eXrX3iUUOrxaaPU0DO2kqx4wBX6iQksRCE@e0ScDUMSi/n8Dw) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BasMwEEWvIsyApTgyjks2MSKBrnuC2AvjTmKBPDKygk1Sb3uAHrEXcRVD29284c/nTW9HdEOLxizg1NnhFafqcCAc@SleJs6Pipcv4ijCxHNR5mX@MQkhNkt82kavtuu1wfdIFHBXWXGxDuum5WCYJgaa@psXD6gVGDn0RvtIRoW@cKjTxt7IS@NZ/gwkCupzVs2hgAOpsyZfrZsCSBr85d2TkyRcdApc@lb7psWBx1O8ARJr8108Rqc9ytYOfg5Wu@KfmSQbXjOakEVA7PvziwH/s25W6y7UN6lBuvp2FtE8L5nM9/sf) - .NET

This is a port of the Perl/PCRE2/.NET version to regex engines lacking nested backreferences.

Although this version is of equal length to the ECMAScript one, it is of interest due to being much faster than it (and the recursive version) on regex engines that support it.

```
          # tail = input number; no need to anchor, as all positive inputs match
x                 # tail -= 1; head += 1
(
    (?=(\3)?)     # \2 = \3, or unset if \3 is unset
    (             # \3
        (?(2)     # Only allow the second alternative to match on the first
                  # iteration, when \2 is unset, and the first alternative to
                  # match on every subsequent iteration.
            \2\2  # \3 = \2 * 2; tail -= \3; head += \3
        |
            x     # \3 = 1; tail -= \3; head += \3
        )
    )
)*                # Iterate the above as many times as possible, minimum 0
                  # Return match = head
```

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl / Java / PCRE / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / Ruby / .NET</sup></sub>), 29 bytes

```
x((?=(\3)?)(\2\2|(?!\4)x()))*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NTsMwEIX3PYWprNpDkuYHssFx40ply4odqayCUrBk0mAHERTMkgNwRC4S3ABi8zTvaebN19ZG5@PjK8KGoUEf7nYa4Zh5y4vN@nq9crP9wVBsecKKFYMBqb13MLRGNR2aV82cOSQ0t61WHSURCe3zre38iQyjNEyhfjoulf9p4nO4wBLYscv6jzsjdJHBIPRNuuVeky1zM4Smz@o3wKrg04KfggAGbBeLCWJi8IAp@2HCaknQ18cnYbjhpCc9VuzlQemaev8eYxPf/@ETRJZUBL4@EpFXYM45KS@vNlKOPaUlp9UZlECrrMreaHlSnUNPAeB0HJMoy/Nv) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVPNbtswDL73KVgDRaT8qEm2XuZ6wVZsQIF2G9pjkoPiyIlSWfIkunHb9boH2CPuRTLa8dYViC80yU@fyI/URt7LwWZ5t9N54TzChnyhnejG8H@kRG0OxrxaqepgJqBXMhcXzhiVovMhPirKhdEppEaGANdSW3iCNhZQIpl7p5eQU4bdotd2BdKvwnTOAdfebQN8qlJVoHZ08gjgszYKssSqbfPLIpG6pRKUj3j8scwy5dXyRsml8rBoYK@D7O/J1s04j9t7Qx/j7brmZywkC@pTLq@0VYzz48SWxnCdsSDU91KawKLTbrcbcf70GrpnYAwPEjwRA/5jIIJTYlgQ7i4OvaQzs53aYvy8jz1/k4jKW/BJ@0fd5kV9QeAxqbFwzihp4THJiFHFcJtKa6l1bYsSIYG62zbGbh8Cqlxoy2No@2xgYi3DF1UhldlIDNAKYqh24tiDLCHaFtv8dA6G0jVKhMJoZNGAhkB4BDukzKVFWhUvCumDIoeZ6XDO@2BHB5PCKLvC9fkYJlAj4R2Z0ZwY07X003nV9tN4djSP4YP38iGITBvDqn6n6jSiAGTO171RGYkdxmDPEzsi0@tRg9cS0zUplBObF/neY80OW3oEF0S@3xix9bJg7RWpKx6@ZjfSrhTdNOxbzutOM/bIW1kdabT1GhWrx8jjxwR9WU/kJV2Qapix6GQJv3/@gpMQkRb9Vk2xcfQEIqBYTpsTSoOBcSqwYLkfvI@iHlmx8q4sKLyXiibGqbTmtbGXVyfQXelQz5OKfKbvqN7VXcXYJGGzN3zC2Ww8G/9gk@PZW17VuO6uXsbdcDA@O/sD) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTRbtowFH3nK26ZWmwIE4F1mggp6rpOe2DthKi0CVBEgwNWgxM5yaAtvO4D9on7kLHrOElDW2lBIrbv9TnnHt/YDcPmwnX3b7hw/WTOoBe6kr1dnlXc5UyCE46nYMOw@nG9vrvtJD/u77@Plu/XS7LfENK3yaRD@5RM2pP2lvSPJu/ohlBK63v6fEPVgHpoO2HDtCpPZFE854FiKy9JLhaHazzAVTZbvcw7q3ARQ4jD2GFSBpK4gYhiSNXXVyyKZgtGH5Gn23UxAXo9yFbVMF1nYu5bIFmcSAGmtUshVzMuCIXHCuATjpHNZ4KEtGlO7ZYFCeZ02k4MgZqpDQscpMkpplaHgTCJLVCeQl0yC8rqUE4YS71bsijxYz1WdXhexGIDgiRG2kW81JHgJ3PjQI47U02FqHYK7rjBKuQ@I6EB3y6Gl86n69H5YABbPbsZff5gwIkm1IOcoUU1FPeAHElGcx@81FOPYDWYbUBVAaXSJMxQSbodjuddOI4mAk@3hKl5MmAPNxAl/kE5lZqzYLHPBSP6VLgwtE/Uwhwz9zwVhdtEC2ucxQEnadJb10FvsckMEKYBYRBhWEc8Luak1qxlxOoRpjIIc47s8rl0u0It9l/BhUaa3wAU0kXyJyx9aIpOsLWejYXZMKcWdtQKCyeRAbVNTQnDUiIMTu3S/sIIbgvVMz1bmBY0GrxccX4UDxRQlCIhtYmoaWsy@1zsCtW8XP1V4c@v31XrAKBgyk7JhpZlPWfR/aO6Lu8htmEukcyAq5vBwACshhtQ9ImRd58BHWq9gFKiM7gz5IPtNkdH69MmvBwOr4fO1fXX89HFl9fUFB9PXmANf/jKu96cQrOYtKbWqwAlHT2UcXLyPxkHjFW4VB1eteAW75s7vAue4@@A@RHLwi@iheFPmg@TDgEL/0ttojN2lfRT6@pPSDKGRdHikspui8pu32q2T0//up4/W0T7pq/O8R8) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLLbtswELz7K9YEEXET@aXaLVya0KVuESBICrW3KCAUlbYEUw9QTGAgzbUfkE/sj7grO22BHEgsd2dmZxdsi/awituiBe5AAZswGEPrzFY709osNyKYjM9jrYvMep03VVta41KRokyTSReEENDZUFJvTQ@oval9J7T@fHm11hpDmCFJkrAclHWpO@MFa3NnxvdZvvOOLm3LqvQsBDaPlvPl@w/RcsFQDjaNE7xUU8mt2pB6J759/3R5jRKfoNwIbm8776ypKcLR7E4pltYMCdw93FOF0uE0HM2w55t9a5sfRrARCwkuiZ83D7XvuauISLckQPf0Tg4Ajp3r1zevV@pYp@jiAuGJAEAGQAwF36njsqrM54XOrBXchdS7357JvAj2QchrDHmFiMDNCW2zzmvjHHXBoVJfk/UXfX2j10lyk8hXdZocTV40/UwSaA0zCf0beD0O4Pevl@CEJKsmywvBK/IKWQf8EU/AAILx3wU9ovzvmu/g7IzM/MOteysfCf7Gna66rTgyn5/f/ABKH/ZCxEqk7zBGkUZp9FPEw3SOe0Gznh8O01G0WPwB) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY89bsMwDIV3n4LQYjL@geUgi10hJ8gJbA8BYqcqVNqQVMQBMvcAPWIv4kot2qXbIx/fR3K5@@eZ95t@XWbrwd1dbsfruOYvbuYWrLJCiG1FPCrs93SkoLCmvu7rx0pEuy34nWwKObSgVZVMswUDmiOqdP6iuUnAKFO6xWiPohCUgJ7AjIyGnuoGTCcHZbpqSCCGOYbtma8javYYDcp/lBwokxR4EaAbWGzsU6yVbH83zm@@vFntR3TeIlOWwuf7RxrHIv/0zY8/lpPmS5izaHMQq9gxNf8YKaRZ5JzCA2dGCkcUfzqcRltV1IfDFw) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BSsNAEIbvPsUYxOyUZElWemm6lEK9ehBvSVmi3aYL22nYJDSiXn0AH9EXiZtUepv5@b@Zz3Wv74MDCc@60n3NSZ9hs35Zc6fLXQZGJhmcD8ZqsLLSbeOjPdg8TrdSBgUFmc9tnnAei20GmnZTwJvampaFcYgXgFtNVXtguBS@kHvaQxfgBmB/ckBgCMaQtydlWJog52Pxuk6HzK0XqjvvMb0yMs2gdoZaoCiE3@8fCCMW9MGMcAQ1dUe2aN5KisAhP5b1x9391eXrX3iUUOrxaaPU0DO2kqx4wBX6iQksRCE@e0ScDUMSi/n8Dw) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BasMwEEWvIsyApTgyjks2MSKBrnuC2AvjTmKBPDKygk1Sb3uAHrEXcRVD29284c/nTW9HdEOLxizg1NnhFafqcCAc@SleJs6Pipcv4ijCxHNR5mX@MQkhNkt82kavtuu1wfdIFHBXWXGxDuum5WCYJgaa@psXD6gVGDn0RvtIRoW@cKjTxt7IS@NZ/gwkCupzVs2hgAOpsyZfrZsCSBr85d2TkyRcdApc@lb7psWBx1O8ARJr8108Rqc9ytYOfg5Wu@KfmSQbXjOakEVA7PvziwH/s25W6y7UN6lBuvp2FtE8L5nM9/sf) - .NET

This is a combination of the no-nested-backreferences and no-conditionals ports, and again, the proviso applies about it being faster than the ECMAScript and recursive versions.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 26 bytes

```
{_0.5+`exp x*`ln 2}'*|=|2\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qON9Az1U5IrShQqNBKyMlTMKpV16qxrTGK4eJKU7AwAwC28AnN)

My first function-less K answer. Port of [Xcoder's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179175/107017).

Explanation:

```
{_0.5+`exp x*`ln 2}'*|=|2\      Main program.
                        2\      Convert to base 2
                       |        Reverse
                      =         Group into falsey and truthy indices
                    *|          Select the second element (i.e. truthy indices)
                   '            For each of them
{                 }             Execute a function that
      `exp x*`ln 2              Raise the argument to the power of 2
 _0.5+                          Then round it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip) `-w`, 115 bytes

```
H!ZZ--ZZZ--ZZZ--ZZZZ-Z-ZZZ-Z-ZZt
@^))e G>)e F>)e E>).d[DC].b[Bze
a,x]dc[(' b[('ca[L'`e'*sece'A]a
 H]--b['*fa['b^-['
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/30MxKkpXNwqZiNKN0oWRJVwOcZqaqQrudkDCDUS42mnqpUS7OMfqJUU7VaVyJepUxKYkR2uoKyQBieTEaB/1hFR1reLU5FR1x9hELgWPWF3dpGh1rbTEaPWkON1o9f///@uWp5smAwA)

Takes a single raw byte as input, and returns some mix of `128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1` and `000 00 00 00 0 0 0 0`

In the TIO, the argument `-wgNN` will provide this program with a byte of value `0xNN`. So, `-wg5c` provides `0x5c`. The special value `-wgkk` will instead generate a random byte.

Chip is a 2D language where each element can interact with its four neighbors with single bit values only. An unsmooshed version of the above would look like this:

```
!ZZZ--ZZZ--ZZZ--ZZZ--ZZ--ZZ--ZZ--Zt
)))---))---))---))---)---)---)---)-e
|||H  ||G  ||F  ||E  |D  |C  |B  |A
xx)]d xx]d xx]d xx]d )]d x]d x]d x]d
xxx]c ))]c xx]c x)]c x]c )]c x]c x]c
x)x]b )x]b ))]b x)]b x]b x]b )]b x]b
)xx]a xx]a )x]a )x]a x]a x]a x]a )]a

s*f
```

Here we can see eight blocks, one for each power of two, from left to right. Each block contains a grid specifying which bits should be turned on for each character of that power. The input bits (capital letters) are connected as switches to control whether each digit should be its actual value, or zero.

Answer (score 0):

## x86 Machine Code, 20 bytes

```
; ECX is the input value ('x')
; EDX is a temporary, used for manipulations of 'x'
; EAX is a counter, which will also be the return value
; EBP is a temporary holding space for the return address

           GetSumOfPowersOf2:
5D            pop    ebp              ; save return address
31 C0         xor    eax, eax         ; counter = 0

           MainLoop:
89 CA         mov    edx, ecx         ; \
F7 DA         neg    edx              ; | temp = (x & -x)
21 CA         and    edx, ecx         ; /
52            push   edx              ; push temp onto stack
40            inc    eax              ; increment counter
89 CA         mov    edx, ecx         ; \ 
4A            dec    edx              ; | x = (x & (x - 1))
21 D1         and    ecx, edx         ; /
75 F1         jne    SHORT MainLoop   ; loop while x != 0

55            push   ebp              ; restore return address
C3            ret                     ; return to return address, with result in EAX
```

These bytes define a function, which takes as input a single 32-bit integer argument in the `ECX` register (the choice of which register to pass the input in is rather arbitrary, but `ECX` is the one used in the `__fastcall` calling convention). This is the value `x` from the question.

`x` is assumed to be non-zero, since it is given that `1 <= x <= 255`. This allows us to only test the loop condition at the *bottom* of the loop.

The bulk of the code is a big ol' loop that calculates the powers of two using binary bit-twiddling and pushes them onto the stack. On x86, the `PUSH` instruction pushes a register value onto the stack and requires only 1 byte to encode, so it's a natural choice. The caller of this function will then just retrieve the return values by `POP`ing them off the stack. Although this is a non-standard convention (by convention, a function's result is either returned in a register or stored into a memory address via a pointer), it works.

Well, as long as you attend to one little detail: the fact that the `CALL` instruction pushes the return address onto the stack, and the fact that the `RET` instruction knows where to return by popping the return address pushed onto the stack by the `CALL` instruction. So, if we want to return values on the stack, we need to preserve the return address at the top of the function. This is done by `POP`ing the value at the top of the stack into the `EBP` register for safe-keeping, `PUSH`ing the return values onto the stack during the loop, and then `PUSH`ing the value in `EBP` (the preserved return address) onto the stack at the position where the `RET` instruction will expect to find it.

With this arrangement, when control returns to the caller, all they'll have to do is `POP` off the return values. Of course, they need to know *how many* values to pop off the stack, so we have to maintain a counter inside of the loop. The `EAX` register was chosen for this counter, since in all x86 calling conventions, functions return their result in the `EAX` register. This function returns as its result the number of values to pop off of the stack.

The caller would do something like this to exercise the function:

```
    mov   ecx, 86             ; put input value ('x') into ECX for passing to function
    call  GetSumOfPowersOf2   ; call the function
    mov   ecx, eax            ; save the function's return value (number of values to pop off stack)
GetAndPrint:
    pop   eax                 ; pop value off of stack into EAX
    call  PrintValueInEAX     ; print the value stored in EAX
    dec   ecx                 ; decrement counter
    jnz   SHORT GetAndPrint   ; loop while counter != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 9 bytes

```
oBL:K2*#.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z/fycfK20hLWe////8WZgA)

```
oB         \ Push binary digits to stack (least significant bit at the top).
  L:       \ len(stack) times do:
    K2*    \     Multiply all items by 2
       #.  \     Pop and print the top item
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 55 bytes

```
f(n)=2^{b[mod(floor(n/2^b),2)=1]}
b=[0...floor(log_2n)]
```

Port of Mr. Xcoder's Jelly answer.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xv3x6esptr)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LOÆ&
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS338D7epLSlOSi6GiixYZGgAYQEA)

Port of Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
LOÆ&  # Implicit input  ->  10
L     # Lowered range   ->  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 O    # Two power       ->  [1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]
  Æ&  # Bitwise AND     ->  [0,2,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0]
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__4oG_OjLilr064oeh4qe7LuKLryAyMzcK), 9 bytes

```
ⁿ:2▽:⇡⧻.⋯
```

`⋯` get the bit representation as a list

`⇡⧻.` make a list of the same length, counting up from 1 [1, 2, ...]

`▽:` keep the values from the incrementing list for which there is a truthy bit in the bit representation list

`ⁿ:2` 2^n